# What should main() return in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, return-value, program-entry-point, return-type

What is the correct (most efficient) way to define the `main()` function in C and C++ — `int main()` or `void main()` — and why? And how about the arguments?
If `int main()` then `return 1` or `return 0`?

Comment: I still think it's fairly vague too.  Define "most efficient" for me.  Efficient in what sense?  In the sense of taking up less memory?  In the sense of running faster?  I can see the useful answers but I still think the question is phrased pretty poorly.

Comment: Pish posh, the context of efficient is obvious here, especially with the examples (which are likely there to clarify the definition of 'efficient'). Hopefully the poor buffer didn't crawl into a hole and regret the question entirely. One could say, regardless of void or int, a value is returned, so it has no impact on file size, operations executed, nor memory allocated. And people, across most OSs, tend to return 0 on success, and something else on -other- success, or failure - but there is no standard. Ultimately, no difference in efficiency in any obvious way.

Comment: "correct (most efficient)" doesn't make sense. Efficient is one thing, correct is another. `main` is called once (and in C++ can only be called once: no recursion). If you don't want execution to spend a lot of time in `main`, then don't invoke the program a large number of times: make the program implement the repetition.

Comment: I find it interesting that none of the answers, as far as I can tell, provide a fully working example, including the `#include` statements

Comment: @puk: there's no need for 'fully working example', and no headers are needed to write `main()` -- even though it would be an unusual program that did not need some headers.

Comment: What every answer here so far fails to mention is that the chapter about main's return type, quoted all over, is a **sub-chapter** of the **hosted environment chapter**, which is turn is a **sub-chapter** of the relevant chapter **Execution environments**. Present answers at this moment only cover 50% of the standard. So I wrote an answer which aims to answer the question to 100%.

Comment: Also related: [What was the rationale for making `return 0` at the end of `main` optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31394171/1708801)

Comment: Return values make no sense on a platform with no OS. You're not returning to anything. If you hit a `return` in `main(...)` on an embedded device, your system goes into an unpredictable state and your washing machine will become self-aware and try to kill you. So, we use `void main()` in that case. This is industry standard practice in bare-metal embedded.

Comment: [What the Microsoft c++ reference says about returning void from main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=msvc-170#returning-void-from-main)

Answer (score 659, accepted):

The return value for `main` indicates how the program exited. Normal exit is represented by a 0 return value from `main`. Abnormal exit is signaled by a non-zero return, but there is no standard for how non-zero codes are interpreted. As noted by others, `void main()` is prohibited by the C++ standard and should not be used. The valid C++ `main` signatures are:

```
int main(void)
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

which is equivalent to

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

It is also worth noting that in C++, `int main()` can be left without a return-statement, at which point it defaults to returning 0. This is also true with a C99 program. Whether `return 0;` should be omitted or not is open to debate. The range of valid C program main signatures is much greater.

Efficiency is not an issue with the `main` function. It can only be entered and left once (marking the program's start and termination) according to the C++ standard. For C, re-entering `main()` is allowed, but should be avoided.

Comment: main CAN be entered/left multiple times, but that program probably wouldn't win any design awards ;)

Comment: C99 also has the C++ mis-feature that reaching the end of the main() function is equivalent to returning 0 -- if main() is defined to return a type compatible with int (section 5.1.2.2.3).

Comment: reentering main is not valid C++. Explicitly in the standard, 3.6.1.3 states 'main shall not be used within a program'

Comment: stdlib.h provides EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE for this purpose

Comment: @korona: using main() from inside the code is undefined behavior. As the compiler may(depending on compiler) insert code to handle program initialization at this point. Running the initialization code twice may not be a good idea.

Comment: 0 and non-zero are correct but entirely meaningless to someone reading your code.  This question is proof that people don't know what valid/invalid codes are.  EXIT_SUCCESS/EXIT_FAILURE are much more clear.

Comment: JaredPar: returning 0 from main is clearly defined in C as a successful termination. Martin York: calling main() from inside a C program is certainly _not_ undefined behavior. I cannot say the same for C++.

Comment: As said, for C++ calling main() is explicitly stated in the standard as illegal (which is a step worse than undefined). For C though, the case is obviously different (but probably best avoided ;))

Comment: It may be clearly defined in the C standard but it's definately not clearly common knowledge.  Otherwise this question wouldn't have been posted.

Comment: JaredPar: well, it's common knowledge among programmers that know C, and usually I'd expect people reading C source to understand C.

Comment: @workmad3, notice this defect report though about using main for GCC: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41431 . Also notice the following for allowed definitions of main: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/a1e5504b499bc58f?pli=1

Comment: Is it guaranteed the return value of the main function will be the exit code of the program? I always used the `exit` function in my programs to set the exit code other than 0.

Comment: @Calmarius: Yes. [Section 5.1.2.2.3 of the standard](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.1.2.2.3.html) says "...a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument..."

Comment: Every C developer knows INT exit code 0 means success, so why so much drowning in a glass of water?

Comment: This answer only covers 50% of the standards as it doesn't mention freestanding implementations. "void main() is explicitly prohibited by the C++ standard"... quotation needed (you won't find one, it rather implicitly prohibits void main() for hosted systems).

Comment: @Lundin `main()` is only talked about for the hosted forms of C and C++. So the question is implicitly about hosted C and C++.

Comment: Technically, the signature should be `unsigned char main(...)`, because the vast majority of shell environments require you to return a value between 0 and 255.

Comment: @Majora320: not really.  The standards say `int` and mean `int`.  However, you're correct that only the least significant 8 bits of the `int` are used as exit status.  See also [Exit codes bigger than 255 — possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/).

Comment: ' is explicitly prohibited by the C++ standard and shouldn't be used' And also by C. Even if 'it works' it's broken. Presumably this is why it's the same way in C++ unless you mean it won't compile? I'm not a fan of C++ but then I know better than writing 'void main()' anyhow so I wouldn't have run into a problem.

Comment: You forgot to mention `int main(void);` as a valid signature in C.  In C, `int main();` really means `int main(...)`.  Only in C++ does `int main()` mean `int main(void)`.  (This is why it's bad that you only talked about C++ signatures for it)

Comment: Zero/non-zero to signal success/error is not true on all platforms (for example VMS). One should use the `EXIT_SUCCESS`/`EXIT_FAILURE` macros in portable code.

Comment: Please give a reference for "*void main() is explicitly prohibited by the C++ standard*", as I find no such prohibition in [basic.start.main](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main).  As long as the standard signatures are supported, an implementation can also support as many non-standard signatures as it wants.  (That said, I'd *strongly* advise against actually using such an extension, even if available).

Comment: @TobySpeight: I would use `void main()` on an embedded system where main doesn't return. We've got a better way to say it now but embedded compilers are behind.

Comment: @TobySpeight> on that very link, it explicitly states that there must be exactly one function called main, and that function must return an `int`. (It also explicitly says that those constraints do not apply to freestanding environments).

Comment: @spectras, how embarrassing!  I should have read that more carefully.  My reading of the requirements is that freestanding environments don't need to require a `main()`, but that any such `main()` that is present still needs to satisfy the rest of the requirements (returning `int`, not being used by the program, etc)

Comment: If I write `EXIT_FAILURE` instead, absolutely nothing happens at the time of running the program. Why so? I stated explicitly that it was a failure, but at the end of the day it looked exactly as if I wrote `EXIT_SUCCESS`

Comment: Edit queue is full but for completeness the post should indicate as of C++11 all of the given signatures have their `auto` variants as valid signatures

Comment: @korona It would: In the [obfuscated C contest](https://www.ioccc.org/1988/phillipps.c)! :-)

Comment: And over the course of 7 years nobody bothered to mention just *why* the usual boolean semantics are inverted for a program's exit code? The realization that there is often just one way to succeed but many ways to fail is a great memory aid.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I immediately thought of that too. Though it's highly unlikely to win now. It's not the only one to do it. That doesn't mean it can't win but it's less likely to do so.

Comment: It should be noted in more recent C standards one does not have to have a `return` in main() either.

Comment: You say that `int main()` can be left without a return-statement, but you also clarify that `int main()` is not a valid C++ siganture. So, can `int main(void)` be left without a return-statement?

Answer (score 220):

The accepted answer appears to be targetted for C++, so I thought I'd add an answer that pertains to C, and this differs in a few ways. There were also some changes made between ISO/IEC 9899:1989 (C90) and ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (C99).

`main()` should be declared as either:

```
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Or equivalent. For example, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` is equivalent to the second one. In C90, the `int` return type can be omitted as it is a default, but in C99 and newer, the `int` return type may not be omitted.

If an implementation permits it, `main()` can be declared in other ways (e.g., `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`), but this makes the program implementation defined, and no longer strictly conforming.

The standard defines 3 values for returning that are strictly conforming (that is, does not rely on implementation defined behaviour): `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` for a successful termination, and `EXIT_FAILURE` for an unsuccessful termination. Any other values are non-standard and implementation defined. In C90, `main()` must have an explicit `return` statement at the end to avoid undefined behaviour. In C99 and newer, you may omit the return statement from `main()`. If you do, and `main()` finished, there is an implicit `return 0`.

Finally, there is nothing wrong from a standards point of view with calling `main()` *recursively* from a C program.

Comment: @ Chris Young : Where is the return value going to. And whats the use of the value returned? Can you explain that. or is it just to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ MELWIN : Return value is passed to the host environment. Most of the time it would be your OS, which can pass this value to some other running process by request (e.g. system() call).

Comment: Regarding "The standard defines 3 values for returning... `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`", is "`0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`" actually part of the ISO-C and C++ specs? If yes, where in the specs?

Comment: C11 §7.22p3 and §7.22.4.4p5. C++11 references the C standard library, but they're briefly mentioned in §18.5p3.

Comment: "If an implementation permits it, main can be declared in other ways, but this makes the program implementation defined, and no longer strictly conforming." Quotation needed.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think you need a quote to say that someone is allowed to make a compiler that accepts non-standard-conforming programs, or to have a non-stardard-conforming compiler. That's common knowledge and common sense

Comment: @KABoissonneault Implementation-defined behavior is a term from the standard, as opposed to completely undocumented behavior. If you implement something that is listed as implementation-defined behavior, you still follow the standard. In this case C89 which was quoted, lists no such implementation-defined behavior, hence the need of quote, to prove that he is not just making things up out of the blue.

Comment: @Lundin You're seeing this the wrong way. What we're talking about is not implementation-defined behavior, we're talking about an implementation deviating from the standard if they choose so.
It's more like a child disobeying their parents: you don't need a quote from the parents to tell you in what way a child can go against what the parents said. You just know that the moment the child chooses to do so, they're no longer compliant with their parents' guildelines

Comment: @KABoissonneault The part I quoted in my comment is definitely about implementation-defined behavior (as opposed to _non-standard compiler extensions_.) Thus I am talking about implementation-defined behavior. If you are having a monologue about something else, best of luck with that.

Comment: @Lundin I guess the wording in the quote is confusing (the part where they say "but this makes the program implementation defined") but I'm pretty sure the person was talking about non-standard behavior (as said in "If an *implementation* permits it" and "and no longer strictly conforming [to the standard]") as opposed to actual implementation defined behavior.
The person should definitely reword their answer, but I still don't think a quote from the standard is necessary on that

Comment: "but this makes the program implementation defined, and no longer strictly conforming." --> Code is still conforming.  Certainly less probable with a implementation defined signature.

Comment: _main() must have an explicit return statement at the end to avoid undefined behaviour._ : only holds for non-main functions.  
The C standard explicitly allows not to put the return statement for the main function, and states that in such a case a `return 0` will be automatically generated by the compiler.  
No UB is triggered in this case. Please see answers below for quotations from the standard.

Comment: @programmersn the part you are quoting in my answer is about C90. If you continue to read the part below (C99) you will see I say that you can omit the return from main() as there's an implicit return 0. That's because this only was added to the standard since C99.

Comment: @Chris My bad I didn't see this part of the answer, jumped right away to conclusion. Could you please make any edit to the answer, just so that I may pull back the downvote. Thanx for the clarification anyway

Answer (score 149):

### Standard C — Hosted Environment

For a hosted environment (that's the normal one), the C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) says:

> #### 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
> prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
> parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
> used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.
>
> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following
> constraints:
>
> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>   intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>   from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
>   shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]`
>   represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the
>   program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is
>   greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]`
>   represent the program parameters.
> - The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
>   be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
>   startup and program termination.
>
> <sup>10)</sup> Thus, `int` can be replaced by a typedef name defined as `int`, or the type of `argv` can be written as
> `char **argv`, and so on.

#### Program termination in C99 or C11

The value returned from `main()` is transmitted to the 'environment' in an implementation-defined way.

> #### 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> 1 If the return type of the `main` function is a type compatible with `int`, a return from the
> initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value
> returned by the `main` function as its argument;<sup>11)</sup> reaching the `}` that terminates the
> `main` function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
> termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.
>
> <sup>11)</sup> In accordance with 6.2.4, the lifetimes of objects with automatic storage duration declared in `main`
> will have ended in the former case, even where they would not have in the latter.

Note that `0` is mandated as 'success'. You can use `EXIT_FAILURE` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` from `<stdlib.h>` if you prefer, but 0 is well established, and so is 1. See also [Exit codes greater than 255 — possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/exitcodes-bigger-than-255-possible/).

In C89 (and hence in Microsoft C), there is no statement about what happens if the `main()` function returns but does not specify a return value; it therefore leads to undefined behaviour.

> #### 7.22.4.4 The `exit` function
>
> ¶5 Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of `status` is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status *successful termination* is returned. If the value of `status` is `EXIT_FAILURE`, an implementation-defined form of the status *unsuccessful termination* is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

### Standard C++ — Hosted Environment

The C++11 standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2011) says:

> #### 3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]
>
> ¶1 A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. [...]
>
> ¶2 An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall
> have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation defined.
> All implementations
> shall allow both of the following definitions of main:
>
> ```
> int main() { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> In the latter form `argc` shall be the number of arguments passed to the program from the environment
> in which the program is run. If `argc` is nonzero these arguments shall be supplied in `argv[0]`
> through `argv[argc-1]` as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated multibyte strings (NTMBSs) (17.5.2.1.4.2) and `argv[0]` shall be the pointer to the initial character of a NTMBS that represents the
> name used to invoke the program or `""`. The value of `argc` shall be non-negative. The value of `argv[argc]`
> shall be 0. [Note: It is recommended that any further (optional) parameters be added after `argv`. —end
> note]
>
> ¶3 The function `main` shall not be used within a program. The linkage (3.5) of `main` is implementation-defined. [...]
>
> ¶5 A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic
> storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end
> of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

The C++ standard explicitly says "It [the main function] shall have a return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation defined", and requires the same two signatures as the C standard to be supported as options. So a 'void main()' is directly not allowed by the C++ standard, though there's nothing it can do to stop a non-standard implementation allowing alternatives.  Note that C++ forbids the user from calling `main` (but the C standard does not).

There's a paragraph of §18.5 **Start and termination** in the C++11 standard that is identical to the paragraph from §7.22.4.4 **The `exit` function** in the C11 standard (quoted above), apart from a footnote (which simply documents that `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined in `<cstdlib>`).

### Standard C — Common Extension

Classically, Unix systems support a third variant:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) { ... }
```

The third argument is a null-terminated list of pointers to strings, each of which is an environment variable which has a name, an equals sign, and a value (possibly empty).  If you do not use this, you can still get at the environment via '`extern char **environ;`'.  This global variable is unique among those in POSIX in that it does not have a header that declares it.

This is recognized by the C standard as a common extension, documented in Annex J:

> ###J.5.1 Environment arguments
>
> ¶1 In a hosted environment, the main function receives a third argument, `char *envp[]`,
> that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to `char`, each of which points to a string
> that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program (5.1.2.2.1).

### Microsoft C

The [Microsoft VS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) compiler is interesting. The web site says:

> The declaration syntax for main is
>
> ```
>  int main();
> ```
>
> or, optionally,
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);
> ```
>
> Alternatively, the `main` and `wmain` functions can be declared as returning `void` (no return value). If you declare `main` or `wmain` as returning void, you cannot return an exit code to the parent process or operating system by using a return statement. To return an exit code when `main` or `wmain` is declared as `void`, you must use the `exit` function.

It is not clear to me what happens (what exit code is returned to the parent or OS) when a program with `void main()` does exit — and the MS web site is silent too.

Interestingly, MS does not prescribe the two-argument version of `main()` that the C and C++ standards require. It only prescribes a three argument form where the third argument is `char **envp`, a pointer to a list of environment variables.

The Microsoft page also lists some other alternatives — `wmain()` which takes wide character strings, and some more.

The Microsoft [Visual Studio 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2005) version of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) does not list `void main()` as an alternative.  The [versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from Microsoft [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) onwards do.

### Standard C — Freestanding Environment

As noted early on, the requirements above apply to hosted environments. If you are working with a freestanding environment (which is the alternative to a hosted environment), then the standard has much less to say. For a freestanding environment, the function called at program startup need not be called `main` and there are no constraints on its return type.  The standard says:

> #### 5.1.2 Execution environments
>
> Two execution environments are defined: freestanding and hosted. In both cases,
> program startup occurs when a designated C function is called by the execution
> environment. All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their initial values) before program startup. The manner and timing of such initialization are otherwise unspecified. Program termination returns control to the execution environment.
>
> #### 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment
>
> In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined. Any library facilities available to a freestanding program, other than the minimal set required by clause 4, are implementation-defined.
>
> The effect of program termination in a freestanding environment is implementation-defined.

The cross-reference to clause 4 Conformance refers to this:

> ¶5 A *strictly conforming program* shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard.<sup>3)</sup> It shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any minimum implementation limit.
>
> ¶6 The two forms of conforming implementation are *hosted* and *freestanding*. A *conforming hosted implementation* shall accept any strictly conforming program. A *conforming freestanding implementation* shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`,
> `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and
> `<stdnoreturn.h>`. A conforming implementation may have extensions (including
> additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any strictly conforming program.<sup>4)</sup>
>
> ¶7 A *conforming program* is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation.<sup>5)</sup>
>
> <sup>3)</sup> A strictly conforming program can use conditional features (see 6.10.8.3) provided the use is guarded by an appropriate conditional inclusion preprocessing directive using the related macro. For example:
>
> ```
> #ifdef __STDC_IEC_559__ /* FE_UPWARD defined */
>     /* ... */
>     fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
>     /* ... */
> #endif
> ```
>
> <sup>4)</sup> This implies that a conforming implementation reserves no identifiers other than those explicitly reserved in this International Standard.
>
> <sup>5)</sup> Strictly conforming programs are intended to be maximally portable among conforming implementations. Conforming programs may depend upon non-portable features of a conforming implementation.

It is noticeable that the only header required of a freestanding environment that actually defines any functions is `<stdarg.h>` (and even those may be — and often are — just macros).

### Standard C++ — Freestanding Environment

Just as the C standard recognizes both hosted and freestanding environment, so too does the C++ standard. (Quotes from ISO/IEC 14882:2011.)

> #### 1.4 Implementation compliance [intro.compliance]
>
> ¶7 Two kinds of implementations are defined: a *hosted implementation* and a *freestanding implementation*. For a hosted implementation, this International Standard defines the set of available libraries. A freestanding
> implementation is one in which execution may take place without the benefit of an operating system, and has an implementation-defined set of libraries that includes certain language-support libraries (17.6.1.3).
>
> ¶8 A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
> use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such programs.
>
> ¶9 Each implementation shall include documentation that identifies all conditionally-supported constructs that it does not support and defines all locale-specific characteristics.<sup>3</sup>
>
> <sup>3)</sup> This documentation also defines implementation-defined behavior; see 1.9.
>
> #### 17.6.1.3 Freestanding implementations [compliance]
>
> Two kinds of implementations are defined: hosted and freestanding (1.4). For a hosted implementation, this International Standard describes the set of available headers.
>
> A freestanding implementation has an implementation-defined set of headers. This set shall include at least the headers shown in Table 16.
>
> The supplied version of the header `<cstdlib>` shall declare at least the functions `abort`, `atexit`, `at_quick_exit`, `exit`, and `quick_exit` (18.5). The other headers listed in this table shall meet the same requirements as for a hosted implementation.

**Table 16 — C++ headers for freestanding implementations**

| Subclause | Header(s) |
| --- | --- |
|  | `<ciso646>` |
| 18.2 Types | `<cstddef>` |
| 18.3 Implementation properties | `<cfloat>` `<limits>` `<climits>` |
| 18.4 Integer types | `<cstdint>` |
| 18.5 Start and termination | `<cstdlib>` |
| 18.6 Dynamic memory management | `<new>` |
| 18.7 Type identification | `<typeinfo>` |
| 18.8 Exception handling | `<exception>` |
| 18.9 Initializer lists | `<initializer_list>` |
| 18.10 Other runtime support | `<cstdalign>` `<cstdarg>` `<cstdbool>` |
| 20.9 Type traits | `<type_traits>` |
| 29 Atomics | `<atomic>` |

### What about using `int main()` in C?

The standard §5.1.2.2.1 of the C11 standard shows the preferred notation — `int main(void)` — but there are also two examples in the standard which show `int main()`: [§6.5.3.4 ¶8](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4p8) and [§6.7.6.3 ¶20](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p20).  Now, it is important to note that examples are not 'normative'; they are only illustrative.  If there are bugs in the examples, they do not directly affect the main text of the standard.  That said, they are strongly indicative of expected behaviour, so if the standard includes `int main()` in an example, it suggests that `int main()` is not forbidden, even if it is not the preferred notation.

> #### 6.5.3.4 The `sizeof` and `_Alignof` operators
>
> …
>
> ¶8 EXAMPLE 3 In this example, the size of a variable length array is computed and returned from a function:
>
> ```
> #include <stddef.h>
>
> size_t fsize3(int n)
> {
>     char b[n+3]; // variable length array
>     return sizeof b; // execution time sizeof
> }
> int main()
> {
>     size_t size;
>     size = fsize3(10); // fsize3 returns 13
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

A function definition like `int main(){ … }` does specify that the function takes no arguments, but does not provide a function prototype, AFAICT. For `main()` that is seldom a problem; but it does mean that if you have recursive calls to `main()`, the arguments won't be checked. For other functions, it is more of a problem — you really need a prototype in scope when the function is called to ensure that the arguments are correct.

You don't normally call `main()` recursively, outside of places like IOCCC — and you are explicitly forbidden from doing so in C++. I do have a test program that does it — mainly for novelty. If you have:

```
int i = 0;
int main()
{
    if (i++ < 10)
        main(i, i * i);
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with GCC and don't include `-Wstrict-prototypes`, it compiles cleanly under stringent warnings. If it's `main(void)`, it fails to compile because the function definition says "no arguments".

Comment: @DavidBowling: A function definition like `int main(){ … }` does specify that the function takes no arguments, but does not provide a function prototype, AFAICT.  For `main()` that is seldom a problem; it means that if you have recursive calls to `main()`, the arguments won't be checked.  For other functions, it is more of a problem — you really need a prototype in scope when the function is called to ensure that the arguments are correct.

Comment: @DavidBowling: You don't normally call `main()` recursively, outside of places like IOCCC.  I do have a test program that does it — mainly for novelty.  If you have `int i = 0; int main() { if (i++ < 10) main(i, i * i); return 0; }` and compile with GCC and don't include `-Wstrict-prototypes`, it compiles cleanly under stringent warnings.  If it's `main(void)`, it fails to compile.

Comment: I'm reading "The C Programming Language" by Dennis Ritchie, and although his ```main( )``` functions have return values, he never precedes ```main( )``` with ```int```. Do you know why? It seems like everyone here is saying that it should be written ```int main( )```, but the creator of C didn't write it that way in his book on ANSI C.

Comment: Because even the 2nd Edn of "The C Programming Language" pre-dates the first standard C (I have a copy with "Based on Draft Proposed ANSI C" blazoned across the top-right corner of the cover).  And in C90, you did not have to include the return type for a function if the return type was `int`.  And if a function was used without a prior declaration, it was assumed to return `int`.  BUT: the C90 standard is not the current standard.  The current standard is C18, superseding C11 and C99. ——— _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ And C99 changed the rules so that you must supply an explicit return type in function declarations and definitions, and the return type of functions is no longer inferred — functions must be defined or declared before they are used. So, the code in K&R does not match the expectations of Modern C, for any plausible definition of Modern C. You should not be working to a standard that is (probably) older than you are without a really good reason. You should be using C18 (which is extremely similar to C11 — I still use C11 in practice, but switching to C18 should be painless).

Comment: Thank you. It was the book recommended in the course that I am taking. Do you have any recommendations for better books? Or should I just look up documentation online as I need it?

Comment: I'd recommend either King "C Programming: A Modern Approach" or Gustedt "Modern C" — see [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), a title which is more grandiose than the Q&A content.

Comment: +1 for this: "It is not clear to me what happens (what exit code is returned to the parent or OS) when a program with `void main()` does exit — and the MS web site is silent too."

Answer (score 67):

I believe that `main()` should return either `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE`. They are defined in `stdlib.h`

Comment: @ChrisYoung There is `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` because some historic operating systems (VMS?) used a different number than 0 to denote success. It's 0 everywhere nowadays.

Comment: @FUZxxl you're correct, but that's not in conflict with my comment. EXIT_SUCCESS can indeed be nonzero, but the standards (C89, C99, C11) all define 0 (as well as EXIT_SUCCESS) to also be an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination.

Comment: @ChrisYoung Thank you for correcting me. I was apparently wrong.

Comment: While this comment is correct and valuable, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @FUZxxl:  It's true the VMS used odd values (like 1) to indicate success and even values (like 0) to indicate failure.  Unfortunately, the original ANSI C standard was interpreted to mean that EXIT_SUCCESS had to be 0, so returning EXIT_SUCCESS from main got exactly the wrong behavior on VMS.  The portable thing to do for VMS was to use `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`, which always did the right thing.

Comment: 5.1.2.2.3 "If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument;11) reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0."

Comment: And then 7.22.4.4. about the exit function: "If the value of status is zero or
EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is
returned. If the value of status is EXIT_FAILURE, an implementation-defined form
of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is
implementation-defined."

Answer (score 51):

Note that the C and C++ standards define two kinds of implementations: freestanding and hosted.

- **C90 hosted environment**

Allowed forms <sup>1</sup>:

```
int main (void)
int main (int argc, char *argv[])

main (void)
main (int argc, char *argv[])
/*... etc, similar forms with implicit int */
```

Comments:

The former two are explicitly stated as the allowed forms, the others are implicitly allowed because C90 allowed "implicit int" for return type and function parameters. No other form is allowed.

- **C90 freestanding environment**

Any form or name of main is allowed <sup>2</sup>.

- **C99 hosted environment**

Allowed forms <sup>3</sup>:

```
int main (void)
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
/* or in some other implementation-defined manner. */
```

Comments:

C99 removed "implicit int" so `main()` is no longer valid.

A strange, ambiguous sentence "or in some other implementation-defined manner" has been introduced. This can either be interpreted as "the parameters to `int main()` may vary" or as "main can have any implementation-defined form".

Some compilers have chosen to interpret the standard in the latter way. Arguably, one cannot easily state that they are not conforming by citing the standard in itself, since it is is ambiguous.

However, to allow completely wild forms of `main()` was probably(?) not the intention of this new sentence. The C99 rationale (not normative) implies that the sentence refers to additional parameters to `int main` <sup>4</sup>.

Yet the section for hosted environment program termination then goes on arguing about the case where main does not return int <sup>5</sup>. Although that section is not normative for how main should be declared, it definitely implies that main might be declared in a completely implementation-defined way even on hosted systems.

- **C99 freestanding environment**

Any form or name of main is allowed <sup>6</sup>.

- **C11 hosted environment**

Allowed forms <sup>7</sup>:

```
int main (void)
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
/* or in some other implementation-defined manner. */
```

- **C11 freestanding environment**

Any form or name of main is allowed <sup>8</sup>.

---

Note that `int main()` was never listed as a valid form for any hosted implementation of C in any of the above versions. In C, unlike C++, `()` and `(void)` have different meanings. The former is an obsolescent feature which may be removed from the language. See C11 future language directions:

> 6.11.6 Function declarators
>
> The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.

---

- **C++03 hosted environment**

Allowed forms <sup>9</sup>:

```
int main ()
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comments:

Note the empty parenthesis in the first form. C++ and C are different in this case, because in C++ this means that the function takes no parameters. But in C it means that it may take any parameter.

- **C++03 freestanding environment**

The name of the function called at startup is implementation-defined. If it is named `main()` it must follow the stated forms <sup>10</sup>:

```
// implementation-defined name, or 
int main ()
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

- **C++11 hosted environment**

Allowed forms <sup>11</sup>:

```
int main ()
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comments:

The text of the standard has been changed but it has the same meaning.

- **C++11 freestanding environment**

The name of the function called at startup is implementation-defined. If it is named `main()` it must follow the stated forms <sup>12</sup>:

```
// implementation-defined name, or 
int main ()
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

---

**References**

1. ANSI X3.159-1989 2.1.2.2 Hosted environment. "Program startup"

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
> defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as
> argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
> function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

2. ANSI X3.159-1989 2.1.2.1 Freestanding environment:

> In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take
> place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type
> of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined.

3. ISO 9899:1999 5.1.2.2 Hosted environment -> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> The function called at program startup is named main. The
> implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall be
> defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

> or with two parameters (referred to here as
> argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to the
> function in which they are declared):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

> or equivalent;9) or in some other implementation-defined
> manner.

4. Rationale for International Standard — Programming Languages — C, Revision 5.10. 5.1.2.2 Hosted environment --> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

> The behavior of the arguments to main, and of the interaction of exit, main and atexit
> (see §7.20.4.2) has been codified to curb some unwanted variety in the representation of argv
> strings, and in the meaning of values returned by main.

> The specification of argc and argv as arguments to main recognizes extensive prior practice.
> argv[argc] is required to be a null pointer to provide a redundant check for the end of the list, also on the basis of common practice.

> main is the only function that may portably be declared either with zero or two arguments. (The number of other functions’ arguments must match exactly between invocation and definition.)
> This special case simply recognizes the widespread practice of leaving off the arguments to main when the program does not access the program argument strings. While many implementations support more than two arguments to main, such practice is neither blessed nor forbidden by the Standard; a program that defines main with three arguments is not strictly conforming (see §J.5.1.).

5. ISO 9899:1999 5.1.2.2 Hosted environment --> 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination

> If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument;11) reaching the `}` that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. If the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

6. ISO 9899:1999 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment

> In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined.

7. ISO 9899:2011 5.1.2.2 Hosted environment -> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup

This section is identical to the C99 one cited above.

8. ISO 9899:1999 5.1.2.1 Freestanding environment

This section is identical to the C99 one cited above.

9. ISO 14882:2003 3.6.1 Main function

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both of the following definitions of main:

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
```

> and

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

10. ISO 14882:2003 3.6.1 Main function

> It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function.

11. ISO 14882:2011 3.6.1 Main function

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall
> allow both
>
> — a function of () returning int and
>
> — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int
>
> as the type of main (8.3.5).

12. ISO 14882:2011 3.6.1 Main function

This section is identical to the C++03 one cited above.

Comment: One question: Do C++ standards mean that the signature of the startup function in freestanding environments is implementation defined as well? For example, an implementation could have defined the startup function to be: `int my_startup_function ()` or `int my_startup_function (int argc, char *argv[])` but can it have, for example: `char my_startup_function (long argc, int *argv[])` as a startup function as well? I guess no, right? Also, isn't that ambiguous as well?

Comment: @Utku It can have any signature, as long as it isn't named `main()` because then it must use one the listed signatures. I would imagine the overwhelmingly most common one would be `void my_startup_function ()`, as it doesn't make sense to return from the program on freestanding systems.

Comment: I see. But if it is allowed to use any name and any signature for the startup function, why not allow to use a different signature for `main` as well? Sorry if that's not a smart question but I couldn't understand the reasoning behind.

Comment: @Utku C and C++ are different there. As for why C++ enforces this, I have no idea, there's no rationale. I suspect the main culprit (pun intended) is [Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main) who early on declared that main must return int, period. Because when he made the first C++ version, he was only used to hosted systems. In the linked post, Stroustrup _still_ seems oblivious about the existence of freestanding implementations: for example, he is ignorantly referring to the hosted implementation sub chapter of the C standard, ignoring the existence of chapter 5.1.2.1.

Comment: Notable thing about C11 standard draft is that even though `func()` is considered obsolete, the draft itself uses `int main()` in its own examples.

Comment: What happened to the three-argument signature `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);`

Comment: @Spencer It was never standard. It is mentioned among "common extensions" in the standard Annex J.5.

Comment: No non-trivial program for a freestanding implementation can be *strictly* conforming, and the Standard imposes no meaningful requirements upon programs that are conforming but not strictly conforming, nor upon how freestanding implementations process any non-trivial programs,.  If a freestanding implementation targets an environment that specifies that execution starts with a function called __reset which is invoked without initializing static objects, and specifies that calling a function __init_static will initialize all static objects, exposing such semantics to C code may be useful.

Answer (score 32):

Return 0 on success and non-zero for error. This is the standard used by UNIX and DOS scripting to find out what happened with your program.

Answer (score 11):

`main()` in C89 and K&R C unspecified return types default to ’int`.

```
return 1? return 0?
```

1. If you do not write a return statement in `int main()`, the closing `}` will return 0 by default.

(In c++ and c99 onwards only, for c90 you must write return statement. Please see [Why main does not return 0 here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677672/why-main-does-not-return-0-here))

2. `return 0` or `return 1` will be received by the parent process. In a shell it goes into a shell variable, and if you are running your program form a shell and not using that variable then you need not worry about the return value of `main()`.

See [How can I get what my main function has returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8626109/775964).

```
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
```

This way you can see that it is the variable `$?` which receives the least significant byte of the return value of `main()`.

In Unix and DOS scripting, `return 0` on success and non-zero for error are usually returned. This is the standard used by Unix and DOS scripting to find out what happened with your program and controlling the whole flow.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `$?` is not an environment variable; it is a shell predefined (or built-in) variable.  The difference is hard to spot, but if you run `env` (without any arguments), it prints the environment, and `$?` won't be shown in the environment.

Comment: Returning 0 automatically when main "falls of the end" is only in C++ and C99 onwards, not in C90.

Comment: @Kaz yes i have updated answer accordingly, Actually i have asked that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677672/why-main-does-not-return-0-here

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind that,even though you're returning an int, some OSes (Windows) truncate the returned value to a single byte (0-255).

Comment: Unix does the same, as do most other operating systems probably. I know VMS does such incredible weird things with it that returning anything other than EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE is asking for trouble.

Comment: MSDN begs to differ: when reported through mscorlib, [an exit code is a signed 32-bit integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This seems to imply that the *C runtime libraries* that truncate exit codes are defective.

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect. On Windows a 32-bit integer is returned (and converted to `unsigned`). This is the same on UNIX systems with 32-bit integers. But UNIX-style shells on either system will typically only retain an unsigned 8-bit integer.

Answer (score 5):

The return value can be used by the operating system to check how the program was closed.

Return value 0 usually means OK in most operating systems (the ones I can think of anyway).

It also can be checked when you call a process yourself, and see if the program exited and finished properly.

It's **NOT** just a programming convention.

Comment: There is nothing in the question indicating that an operative system is present. Returning a value doesn't make any sense in a freestanding system.

Answer (score 4):

The return value of `main()` shows how the program exited. If the return value is `zero` it means that the execution was successful while any non-zero value will represent that something went bad in the execution.

Answer (score 4):

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

Additionally, the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md) contains multiple instances of omitting `return 0;` at the end of `main` and no instances in which an explicit return is written.  Although there is not yet a specific guideline on this particular topic in that document, that seems at least a tacit endorsement of the practice.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: **Note**: The purpose for this answer is to allow those of us frequently giving this advice on CodeReview a StackOverflow answer to which we can point to regarding the practice of omitting `return 0;`

Comment: This is bad advice because compilers that implement only C89, not any later standard, are _still_ extremely common (I write this in 2017) and will remain extremely common for the foreseeable future.  For instance, last I checked _no_ version of Microsoft's compilers implemented C99, and it is my understanding that this is also still typical for embedded-system compilers that aren't GCC.

Comment: @zwol: Anyone who has no choice but to use a compiler that is out of date by 28 years probably has more problems than deciding whether to explicitly include `return 0;`, however I would note that many compilers of that era also implemented an implicit `return 0;` even before it was standardized.

Comment: What you say is true.  I mean only to give a rationale for the "bad advice" reaction which is not just "it looks weird".

Comment: Actually, I do a lot of embedded systems work and haven't encountered a compiler that doesn't support implicit `return 0` for over a decade.  Also current versions of Microsoft C [support it as well](http://rextester.com/QICBA7138).  Perhaps your information is out of date?

Answer (score 4):

> What is the correct (most efficient) way to define the main() function in C and C++ — int main() or void main() — and why?

Those words "(most efficient)" don't change the question.  Unless you're in a freestanding environment, there is one universally correct way to declare `main()`, and that's as returning `int`.

> What should `main()` return in C and C++?

An `int`, pure and simple.  And it's more than "what should `main()` return", it's "what *must* `main()` return".  `main()` is, of course, a function that someone else calls.  You don't have any control over the code that calls `main`.  Therefore, you must declare `main` with a type-correct signature to match its caller.  You simply don't have any choice in the matter.  You don't have to ask yourself what's more or less efficient, or what's better or worse style, or anything like that, because the answer is already perfectly well defined, for you, by the C and C+ standards.  Just follow them.

> If int main() then return 1 or return 0?

0 for success, nonzero for failure.  Again, not something you need to (or get to) pick: it's defined by the interface you're supposed to be conforming to.

Answer (score 3):

Returning 0 should tell the programmer that the program has successfully finished the job.

Comment: Returning 1 from `main()` normally signals an error occurred; returning 0 signals success.  If your programs always fail, then 1 is OK, but it not the best idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: The meaning of returning `1` from `main` is implementation-defined. The only language-defined values are `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS` (often defined as `0`), and `EXIT_FAILURE`. In OpenVMS, `return 1;` denotes *successful* termination.

Comment: VMS is not 'normal' — within the meaning of what I said.  Isn't it something like 'any odd value is success; even values are failure' on VMS?

Answer (score 2):

If you really have issues related to efficiency of returning an integer from a process, you should probably avoid to call that process so many times that this return value becomes an issue.

If you are doing this (call a process so many times), you should find a way to put your logic directly inside the caller, or in a DLL file, without allocate a specific process for each call; the multiple process allocations bring you the relevant efficiency problem in this case.

In detail, if you only want to know if returning 0 is more or less efficient than returning 1, it could depend from the compiler in some cases, but generically, assuming they are read from the same source (local, field, constant, embedded in the code, function result, etc.) it requires exactly the same number of clock cycles.

Answer (score 2):

What to return depends on what you want to do with the executable. For example if you are using your program with a command line shell, then you need to return 0 for a success and a non zero for failure. Then you would be able to use the program in shells with conditional processing depending on the outcome of your code. Also you can assign any nonzero value as per your interpretation, for example for critical errors different program exit points could terminate a program with different exit values , and which is available to the calling shell which can decide what to do by inspecting the value returned.
If the code is not intended for use with shells and the returned value does not bother anybody then it might be omitted. I personally use the signature `int main (void) { .. return 0; .. }`

Comment: The format of main() is determined by the implementation, meaning compiler. The programmer does not get chose which form to pick, except when a compiler supports several forms.

Comment: @Lundin The return type will be implementation by the implementation. But the value which to be returned is decided by the programmer. C99 Section 5.1.2.2.3 mentions that the return type of `main` is compatible with `int`. Therefore returning `int` will not be a problem. Although other return types are allowed, but in that case the environment variable having the return value will be unspecified.

But If a programmer does `return 0;` then in bash it can be used to make branches.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small demonstration of the usage of return codes...

When using the various tools that the Linux terminal provides one can use the return code for example for error handling after the process has been completed. Imagine that the following text file myfile is present:

> This is some example in order to check how grep works.

When you execute the grep command a process is created. Once it is through (and didn't break) it returns some code between 0 and 255. For example:

```
$ grep order myfile
```

If you do

```
$ echo $?
$ 0
```

you will get a 0. Why? Because [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) found a match and returned an exit code 0, which is the usual value for exiting with a success. Why that is probably lies in the boolean nature of a simple check whether everything is ok or not. A simple negation of a 0 (boolean false) returns 1 (boolean true), which can easily be handled in a if-else statements.

Let's check it out again but with something that is not inside our text file and thus no match will be found:

```
$ grep foo myfile
$ echo $?
$ 1
```

Since grep failed to match the token "foo" with the content of our file the return code is 1 (this is the usual case when a failure occurs but as stated above you have plenty of values to choose from). Again if we put this in the simple boolean context (everything is ok or not) negating the 1 (boolean true) yields a 0 (boolean false), which again can easily be handled by an if-else statement. When it comes to boolean values anything that is not a 0 is considered to be equivalent to 1 (so 2, 3, 4 etc. in a simple if-else statement for checking whether an error has occurred or not will work the same way as if a 1 was used). You can use different return values to increase the granularity of your error state. It is considered a bad practice to use anything but a 0 for the state of successful execution (due to the reasons given above).

The following bash script (simply type it in a Linux terminal) although very basic should give some idea of error handling:

```
$ grep foo myfile
$ CHECK=$?
$ [ $CHECK -eq 0] && echo 'Match found'; [ $CHECK -ne 0] && echo 'No match was found'
$ No match was found
```

After the second line nothing is printed to the terminal since "foo" made grep return 1 and we check if the return code of grep was equal to 0. The second conditional statement echoes its message in the last line since it is true due to CHECK == 1.

As you can see if you are calling this and that process it is sometimes essential to see what it has returned (by the return value of main()), e.g. when running tests.

Comment: In a shell script, you'd use `if grep foo myfile; then echo 'Match found'; else echo 'No match was found'; fi` — testing the return status directly. If you want to capture the status (for reporting, etc), then you do use an assignment. You might use `if grep foo myfile; CHECK=$?; [ "$CHECK" = 0 ]; then echo  'Match found'; else echo 'No match was found'; fi` or you might use three lines. You might also use options `-s` and `-q` to `grep` to prevent the matches or routine error messages from appearing. However, this is shell minutiae — the key point, that the exit status can be useful — is OK.

Answer (score 1):

"int" is now mandated by the ISO for both C and C++ as the return type for "main".

Both languages previously allowed implicit "int", and for "main" to be declared without any return type. In fact, the very first external release of C++, itself (Release E of "cfront" from February 1985), which is written in its own language, declared "main" without any return type ... but returned an integer value: the number of errors or 127, whichever was smaller

As to the question of *what* to return: the ISO standards for C and C++ work in synchronization with the POSIX standard. For any hosted environment conforming to the POSIX standard,
(1) 126 is reserved for the OS's shell to indicate utilities that are not executable,
(2) 127 is reserved for the OS's shell to indicate that a command that is not found,
(3) the exit values for utilities are separately spelled out on a utility-by-utility basis,
(4) programs that invoke utilities outside the shell should use similar values for their own exits,
(5) the values 128 and above are meant for use to indicate termination that results from receiving a signal,
(6) the values 1-125 are for failures,
(7) the value 0 is for success.

In C and C++ the value EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE are meant for use to handle the most common situation: for programs that report a success or just a generic failure. They may, but need not, be respectively equal to 0 and 1.

That means if you want a program to return different values for different failure modes or status indications, while continuing to make use of those two constants, you might have to resort to first making sure that your additional "failure" or "status" values lie strictly between max(EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE) and 126 (and hope that there's enough room in-between), and to reserve EXIT_FAILURE to mark the generic or default failure mode.

Otherwise, if you're not going to use the constants, then you should go by what POSIX mandates.

For programs meant for use on free-standing environments or on hosts that are not POSIX-compliant, I can say nothing more, except the following:

I have written free-standing programs -- as multi-threaded programs on a custom run-time system (and a custom tool-base for everything else). The general rule I followed was that:
(1) "main" ran the foreground processes, which usually consisted only of start-up, configuration or initialization routines, but could have just as well included foreground processes meant for continual operation (like polling loops),
(2) "main" returns into an infinite sleep & wait loop,
(3) no return value for "main" was defined or used,
(4) background processes ran separately, as interrupt-driven & event-driven threads, independently of "main", terminated only by the receipt of a reset signal or by other threads ... or by simply shutting off the monitoring of whatever event was driving the thread.

Answer (score 0):

In C, the [Section 5.1.2.2.1 of the C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> It shall be defined with a **return type of `int`** and with no
> parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though
> any names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they
> are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```

However for some beginners like me, an abstract example would allow me to get a grasp on it:

When you write a method in your program, e.g. `int read_file(char filename[LEN]);`, then you want, as the caller of this method to know if everything went well (because failures can happen, e.g. file could not be found). By checking the return value of the method you can know if everything went well or not, it's a mechanism for the method to signal you about its successful execution (or not), and let the caller (you, e.g. in your main method) decide how to handle an unexpected failure.

So now imagine I write a C program for a micro-mechanism which is used in a more complex system. When the system calls the micro-mechanism, it wants to know if everything went as expected, so that it can handle any potential error. If the C program's main method would return void, then how would the calling-system know about the execution of its subsystem (the micro-mechanism)? It cannot, that's why main() returns int, in order to communicate to its caller a successful (or not) execution.

In other words:

The rational is that the host environment (i.e. Operating System (OS)) needs to know if the program finished correctly. Without an int-compatible type as a return type (eg. void), the "status returned to the host environment is unspecified" (i.e. undefined behavior on most OS).

Answer (score -4):

On Windows, if a program crashes due to an access violation, the exit code will be `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xC0000005)`.  Similar for other kinds of crashes from an x86 exception as well.

So there are things other than what you return from `main` or pass to `exit` that can cause an exit code to be seen.

Comment: This question is about what `main` returns; not other ways a program can finish