# How do I get fgetc to print all the characters of a file inside of a loop

Tags: c, fgetc

I'm playing around with fgetc and was wondering how I would get my loop to print the line section once then print the first 16 characters.

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb+")) == '\0')
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return 0;
    }

    getchar(fp);

    return 0;
}

void getchar(FILE *fp)
{
    int c;
    size_t linecount = 0;

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("line : ");
        printf("%c ", c);
        linecount++;

        if(linecount == 16)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I want my output to be something like:

```
 line: ? 5 d s d a d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 line: a d s x c v d 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I've tried printing the characters using this for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
   printf("%c ", c);
}
```

But that didn't get the other characters, because the loop was still concentrated on the first character

Comment: are you sure your input file has at least 17 chars?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, there is already a standard function called `getchar()` defined in `<stdio.h>` - you must change the name of your function, or your may get some very strange behaviour.

Secondly, it seems to me that what you want to do is:

- Print out `"line: "`;
- Read a character and print it, until end of file or you have printed 16 characters;
- Print out `"\n"`.

This would translate into code form as:

```
printf("line : ");

while (linecount < 16 && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    printf("%c ", c);
    linecount++;
}

printf("\n");
```

Comment: Could be changed to print `"line:"` and then " %c" in the loop if the excess space character on the end of each line were undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> if((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb+")) == '\0')
> ```

The ASCII `NUL` character is not the same as the `NULL` pointer. This should be `== NULL`, or `if(!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb+"))) /* ... */`, whichever you think is easier to read. The `return 0` in this clause should probably be `return 1`, so it is easier to work with your program in standard pipelines. (Errors in programs are made clear by a non-zero return value. Yes, it's a bit backwards, but there's [good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475181/1-false-and-0-true/6475211#6475211).)

> ```
> void getchar(FILE *fp)
> ```

Oops. `getchar(3)` already exists in the `<stdio.h>` header. Redefining it is not a good idea. (It might work now, but a future modification might completely fail for non-obvious reasons.)

I've re-worked the loop in the `gc()` routine a little, it should do what you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void gc(FILE * fp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb+")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    gc(fp);

    return 0;
}

void gc(FILE * fp)
{
    int c;
    size_t linecount = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (linecount == 0)
            printf("line : ");

        printf("%c ", c);

        if (++linecount == 16) {
            printf("\n");
            linecount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The output when run on itself:

```
$ ./printer printer.c | head
line : # i n c l u d e   < s t d i o . 
line : h > 

 v o i d   g c ( F I L E 
line :   *   f p ) ; 

 i n t   m a i 
line : n ( i n t   a r g c ,   c h a r 
line :   * a r g v [ ] ) 
 {
```

Comment: Note that `'\0'` is an integer constant expression with value 0, and therefore is a valid null pointer constant (but still indicates considerable confusion).