# (Extreme Noob here) Why wont this C code work?

Tags: c

Why won't this work, I'm very new to programming but I can't seem to figure out why this wont work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int num1;
    printf("Enter 1, 2, 3.");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    if(num1 = 1)
        printf("You entered one");
    else if(num1 = 2)
        printf("You entered two");
    else if(num1 = 3)
        printf("You entered three");
    else
        printf("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: If you use `gcc` to compile, I would recommend that you include flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra` to avoid issues like this in the future.

Comment: Won't work **how**? Always include *what you expect*, and *what you're seeing instead*, and *why you think that's surprising*.

Comment: `if (2 == x)` and you won't do the same mistake again... :)

Comment: @effeffe: Or turn on warnings, and formulate conditions in a reasonable, non-Yoda way.

Comment: Kudos for starting to learn programming with C!

Answer (score 9):

In C it is valid to use assignment (int x = 5) within a conditional (if statement).

For example:

```
int x = 0;

if (x = 5)
{

}
```

This will evaluate to true (it returns 5 to the "if" and [all non zero terms are true by convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475181/1-false-and-0-true)) if the assignment could be done and the value != 0.  Which, in this case, it can be done and returns 5.

You were likely looking for this:

```
int x = 0;

if (x == 5)
{

}
```

This will evaluate to false (0).

Remember: You use a single equal sign "=" to mean "assignment".  Use a double equal sign "==" to mean "comparison".

Comment: Use a double equal sign "==" to mean **comparison**

Comment: Better way to put it.  Updated :)

Comment: Note that the assignment will return 5, not 1 -- that still evaluates as true as far as the if statement is concerned, but it isn't "true".

Comment: That was just mindless error.  Hahah.  Fixed.  I meant to say "evaluate to" again.  I was just in a rush and careless.

Answer (score 6):

Replace all the `=` with `==` and you should be fine (because = is used for assignment, while == is used to test for equality, which seems to be what you want to do)

Comment: I'm surprised that the OP compiler does not warn for this.

Comment: @MartinJames OPs tend to use compilers without warnings :)

Comment: Ohh yeah, wow can't believe I forgot about that, Thank you. :)

Comment: That's probably against SO rules but...Hi @Elazar :)

Comment: @user2446045 add `-Wall -Wextra` to turn on compiler warnings

Comment: @user2446045 - try to compile with `-Wall` flag

Answer (score 2):

In C, as in other many programming languages, the **=** operator means "assignment". When you do a = 3, that means "assign a with 3", which of course it's something that succeeds and returns true, that's why your program will always enter the first branch.

What you have to do is use the "equality testing" operator, **==**, so that a == 3 returns true if and only if the value held by variable a is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your code having one mistake you have taken = instead  of  ==,  in C = operator means  assignment operator while== operator is used for comparision.

To clear about your doubts regarding operators read this link 
     http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Answer (score 0):

And because you started with int main() just for compiler reasons put return 0; at the end of your program to be more correct.

Comment: From C99 the `return 0;` is implicit, and if we want to be correct, the signature should be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you need to change the `=` sign to `==`. You use the equal sign sometimes when you declare a int or char. `==` is meaning equal to and you want to use that when your not declaring ints and chars.While `!=` means not equal.You should also put a return 0; at the end of your program.