# Why `Number(new Boolean(false)) === 0`

Tags: javascript

`Boolean(new Boolean(...)) === true` because `new Boolean(...)` is an object.

But why `Number(new Boolean(false)) === 0` (`+new Boolean(false) === 0`) and `Number(new Boolean(true)) === 1`? Why not `NaN`*?

Why in the first example there is no unboxing, but in the second case there is it?

---

*`isNaN(Number({})) === true`

Comment: `Number` calls `toPrimitive`, which will unbox the boolean.

Comment: `Number` converts an object to a numeric. The boolean values `true` and `false` are converted to `1` and `0`, and `Boolean` objects follow the same logic. Also, I'm not sure what you mean about there being no unboxing.

Comment: `Boolean` doesn't do this, it has a very simple table, which it follows, whether the result should be `true` or `false`. In that table, as you noticed, objects get interpreted as `true`. "Why" is a difficult question, but that's how the spec is. A different example is, that `Number({ valueOf: _ => 4}) === 4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ASDFGerte mentioned. This is because the `ToNumber()` method which is called by the [`Number()` constructor](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-number-objects) will call [`.ToPrimitive()` on the argument if an object is passed](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber). This is why it's treated as a Boolean primitive rather than an object.

Comment: Just to mention that `ToPrimitive` is an internal function (along with `ToNumber`) that calls `[Symbol.toPrimitive]`, `.valueOf`, and `.toString` methods (in varying order), and not to be confused with a `.toPrimitive` method on an object, which has no special meaning in JS.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean objects have a `valueOf` method, and it can be used to customize the primitive value of the object in type conversions.

[`Boolean#valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/valueOf) returns `true` for `new Boolean(true)` and `false` for `new Boolean(false)`.

This method is internally called by both the `Number` function and the unary plus (`+`) operator, so the code becomes to:

```
Number(true)
```

which is equal to `1`, as `true` has the numeric value of 1.

---

You can also implement a `valueOf` function on any object, to make it have a custom value, for example:

```js
const object={
    valueOf(){
        return 10
    }
}
console.log(Number(object)) //10
```

Answer (score 1):

> isNaN(Number({})) === true

While this is *correct*, I think you're equating *an* object with *a `Boolean`* object and the two are not equivalent.

Let's start from the most important thing - `Number` converts the argument its given into a numeric. However, it doesn't arbitrarily do that - there are [rules about numeric conversion](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) and when it comes to objects, it's not as simple as "all objects are `NaN`". Consider this:

```js
const obj0 = {}

const obj1 = {
  toString() {
    return 1;
  }
}

const obj2 = {
  toString() {
    return 1;
  },
  valueOf() {
    return 2;
  }
}

const obj3 = {
  toString() {
    return 1;
  },
  valueOf() {
    return 2;
  },
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
    return 3;
  }
}

const obj4 = Object.create(null);

console.log(Number(obj0)); //NaN
console.log(Number(obj1)); //1
console.log(Number(obj2)); //2
console.log(Number(obj3)); //3
console.log(Number(obj4)); //Error
```

Not all objects are equal when converting to a number. Some happen to be even more unequal than others.

When `Number` is given an object, it goes through the process to convert it [to a primitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) with a preference (hint) for a number. To do this, it will go through the following steps:

1. Determine the hint to be "number".
2. Check if the object implements the `@@toPrimitive` method.

   - if so, it will call it with the hint ("number")
3. If that doesn't exist it will then look for a `valueOf` method.

   - this is done because the hint is "number", so `valueOf` will be checked first.
4. If that doesn't exist, then it will check for a `toString` method

   - again, this is based on the hint being "number". If the hint was "string", the last two steps would be reversed.
5. If that doesn't exist, then raise an error.

Once an appropriate method has been found, it's executed and the value returned will be transformed into numeric.

We haven't touched `Boolean` yet - this is just how the generic `Number` does the conversion. So, in summary - an object *can* be converted to a primitive number, if it implements the correct functionality to do so.

`Boolean` objects *do* implement the correct functionality - they [have a `valueOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/valueOf) that returns the primitive boolean they hold:

```js
const T1 = new Boolean(true);
const T2 = new Boolean(true);

console.log("T1.valueOf()", T1.valueOf());
console.log("typeof T1.valueOf()", typeof T1.valueOf());
console.log("T1 === T2", T1 === T2);
console.log("T1.valueOf() === T2.valueOf()", T1.valueOf() === T2.valueOf());
```

So, in that case:
`Number(new Boolean(true))` = `Number(new Boolean(true).valueOf())` = `Number(true)`

And if we generalise it a bit, then: `Number(new Boolean(bool))` = `Number(bool)`

From the [`ToNumber` conversion](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber) we know that `true` is turned into `1` while `false` is turned into `0`. Thus the equality `Number(new Boolean(false)) === 0` makes perfect sense, since `Number(false)` is indeed `0`. Same with `Number(new Boolean(true)) === 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `true` represents 1

and `false` represents 0

> `0` is `false` because they’re both zero elements in common
>   [semirings][Semiring on Wikipedia]. Even though they are distinct data
>   types, it makes intuitive sense to convert between them because they
>   belong to isomorphic algebraic structures.
>
> - `0` is the identity for addition and zero for multiplication. This is true for integers and rationals, but *not* IEEE-754 floating-point
>     numbers: `0.0 * NaN = NaN` and `0.0 * Infinity = NaN`.
> - `false` is the identity for Boolean *xor* (⊻) and zero for Boolean *and* (∧). If Booleans are represented as {0, 1}—the set of integers modulo 2—you can think of ⊻ as addition without carry and ∧ as
>     multiplication.
> - `""` and `[]` are identity for concatenation, but there are several operations for which they make sense as zero. Repetition is one, but
>     repetition and concatenation do not distribute, so these operations
>     don’t form a semiring.
>
> Such implicit conversions are helpful in small programs, but in the
>   large can make programs more difficult to reason about. Just one of
>   the many tradeoffs in language design.
>
> [Semiring on Wikipedia]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring

quote [from](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198284/why-is-0-false)

read this

[1 = false and 0 = true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475181/1-false-and-0-true)