# Why is the exit code 255 instead of -1 in Perl?

Tags: perl, exit

Why is it that when I shift the exit code, $?, in Perl by eight, I get 255 when I expect it to be -1?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you expect the exit code to be -1.

Comment: Please show the Perl code. What program/script 'emits' the exit code, what script reports it?

Comment: `perl -e "exit -1"; echo $?` => 255.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The exit status returned by 'wait()' is a 16-bit value.  Of those 16 bits, the high-order 8 bits come from the low-order 8 bits of the value returned by 'exit()' — or the value returned from `main()`.  If the program dies naturally, the low-order 8 bits of the 16 are all zero.  If the program dies because of signal, the low-order 8 bits encode the signal number and a bit indicating whether a core dump happened.  With a signal, the exit status is treated as zero — programs like the shell tend to interpret the low-order bits non-zero as a failure.

```
15      8 7      0   Bit Position
+-----------------+
|  exit  | signal |
+-----------------+
```

Most machines actually store the 16-bit value in a 32-bit integer, and that is handled with unsigned arithmetic.  The higher-order 8 bits of the 16 may be all 1 if the process exited with 'exit(-1)', but that will appear as 255 when shifted right by 8 bits.

If you really want to convert the value to a signed quantity, you would have to do some bit-twiddling based on the 16th bit.

```
$status >>= 8;
($status & 0x80) ? -(0x100 - ($status & 0xFF)) : $status;
```

See also [SO 774048](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774048/how-to-use-system-calls-like-fork-wait-and-exit-in-c-to-solve-my-problem/) and [SO 179565](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/exitcodes-bigger-than-255-possible/).

Answer (score 10):

Perl returns a subprocess exit code in the same manner as the C runtime library macro `WEXITSTATUS`, which has the following description in `wait(2)`:

```
   WEXITSTATUS(status)
          evaluates to the least significant eight bits of the return code
          of the child which terminated, which may have been  set  as  the
          argument  to  a  call  to exit() or as the argument for a return
          statement in the main program.  This macro can only be evaluated
          if WIFEXITED returned non-zero.
```

The important part here is the *least significant eight bits*. This is why you are getting an exit code of 255. The [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) man page describes `$?` as follows:

```
   $?      The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (‘‘) com-
           mand, successful call to wait() or waitpid(), or from the sys-
           tem() operator.  This is just the 16-bit status word returned
           by the wait() system call (or else is made up to look like it).
           Thus, the exit value of the subprocess is really ("$? >> 8"),
           and "$? & 127" gives which signal, if any, the process died
           from, and "$? & 128" reports whether there was a core dump.
```

There is no special handling here for negative numbers in the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Which way are you shifting it?  Please provide a code example.

also:

```
perldoc -f system
```

gives a very easy to understand example of what to do with $?

Also, http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Exit values should be between 0 and 255.  Your shifting combined with how negative values are actually stored by the computer should give some insight.