# Capturing the return code from java in a shell script

Tags: java, shell

I am invoking a java program from a shell script "TC Shell Script" and the java program returns status codes which represent certain conditions.

The return code of the java prgram is captured in the pre-defined status variable of the TC Shell.

The return codes are captured fine.

The problem I'm facing is when the java program returns or terminates with -1 with System.exit(-1) the shell script is getting 255 as the return code.

All positive numbers are captured fine in the shell script only -1 is being read as 255.

How can i solve this.

Comment: Sounds like a byte value has wrapped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726447/why-is-the-exit-code-255-instead-of-1-in-perl

Comment: I guess you mean `tcsh`? This is commonly referred to as the Tenex C shell or simply as `tcsh`. There is a broad movement away from the C shell family; perhaps you should switch to Bash or Zsh (though  for this question, it doesn't matter really).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return codes from executables are a small positive number.  Negative numbers get converted to unsigned.  There is no way to get a negative number into the exit code.