# What does it mean when I get a huge exit status when closing a pipe in perl

Tags: perl, pipe

I run a script using a pipe

```
my $pid = open (OUTPUT, "$my_script") || "";
if (! $pid) {
  die("error");
}
while (<OUTPUT>) {
  print;
}
close (OUTPUT);
my $exit_status = $?>>8;
print "$exit_status";
```

Some times I get a long exit status: 72057594037927935

What does this mean? What could cause this?

Comment: I guess you are using a 64 bit version of Perl.
The number you posted is the same as -1 (`0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`) shifted by 8 bits.  I think the 'real' exit status is -1.

Comment: There is something wrong going here as the exit code has to be on the range `0..255`, `-1` is not a valid exit code. Probably, some error checking would help (after `open` and `close`).

Comment: @salva you are right, I'm unable to reproduce this constantly. I tried a script that always exits with exit status -1, but I get 255 instead of this long number... I don't know how to reproduce this issue constantly

Comment: @Morad, even if you call `exit(-1)` the value is truncated to 1 byte. See [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html).

Comment: Have you set `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE'` in some other part of your program?

Comment: @salva No but I'm setting signal handlers for ALRM, TERM, INT and USR2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76435/discussion-between-salva-and-morad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a long number because the value of `$?` is -1.  Right shifting it 8 bits yields the large number you get.  Try this:

```
print -1>>8;
```

`$?` is `-1` because the `close()` function fails for some reason, and not because the script exits with exit status `-1`.

When the `close()` succeeds and the script exits with `-1` then the value of `$?` won't be `-1`, but the value `$?>>8` will be `255` as described here: [Why is the exit code 255 instead of -1 in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726447/why-is-the-exit-code-255-instead-of-1-in-perl)