# C++ Programs return int type, so why does return -1 return 255?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, integer, return-value

Note that I am running a linux machine, although I don't think the result is different on a windows (or other) machine.

This is a simple question - C++ programs usually return a 32 bit int. If I `return -1`, and then print the result from the terminal, the result is `255`.

Why is this? I feel link this is something I should know, or should have noticed many years ago - I never really used return codes before now or thought about it before.

Test C++ program:

```
int main()
{
    return -1;
}
```

Compile:

```
g++ main.cpp -o a.out
```

Run:

```
./a.out
```

Check result:

```
echo $?
```

Result:

```
255
```

I would have expected to see 2^32 - 1.

Why is the result `255` not `-1` or even `4294967295`. (`2^32 - 1`)

Comment: Duplicate/related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5149228/

Comment: "At the present time, most Unix-based systems only support 8-bit return values."

Comment: "I don't think the result is different on a windows" wrong [ExitCodes bigger than 255, possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/179565/995714) Windows can use the whole 32-bit range

Comment: [Why is the exit code 255 instead of -1 in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2726447/995714)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because (not all) OS's use the whole return value. In this case, it's truncated to the low 8 bits. It's up to the OS (and other related components, such as the shell) to "use" and "retain" this value, and it's what's called an "implementation detail", in other words, the C and C++ standards do not dicate what the usefulness or meaning of the return value is [aside from the paragraph below] - just that from the C perspective it is an `int` - the C program may be started in an environment where that value is ignored, truncated, extended or multiplied by 432 and it's still a valid C or C++ environment.

The C standard says that the value `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` (which should have the value zero as I understand it) and the value `EXIT_FAILURE` (some non-zero value) should be considered success and failure respectively. However, all other values are "implementation defined" and thus under the rules of the OS/environment that the execution happens in.

Note that when the shell (or whatever runs your program), it does not jump straight to your `main`, but some other functionality is performed first to initialize things that are needed by your `main` function. And once `main` has returned/exited, there is usually some code that executes AFTER your program as well. Exactly how this works is dependent on several things:

- who wrote the compiler and/or runtime library
- what OS it is designed for
- what processor architecture it is
- potentially what shell/runtime/OS functionality started the process

The C and C++ standard doesn't define these things, as doing so would potentially affect the actual platforms that can/will run C and/or C++ applications, and the goal of C and C++ is to "be inclusive" - in other words, try to not limit the environment, processor, etc that the languages support.

Comment: The C standard mandates that a status return of 0 or EXIT_SUCCESS should be interpreted as indicating successful termination, while EXIT_FAILURE indicates unsuccessful termination. The interpretation of any other value is implementation-defined.

Comment: Ok, I have added a paragraph to say that.

Answer (score 7):

The return value is defined as an int, but legal values for exit codes are only 0-255.

You can think of it as if the operating system is doing (unsigned char)main() internally.

Added explanation per comment request:

- The fact that only lower eight bits are interpreted is defined in
  POSIX (see `exit` function documentation). Different operating systems may have different opinions
- In terms of machine code, it is important to realize that your main function is probably not the real entry point of your program. The real entry point of your program is provided by the C library and takes care of setting up the environment and calling your `main`. It also takes care of accepting the return value and calling `exit(your_return_value)`. But as others have noted, this is an implementation detail, not part of the C standard (there is difference between C and posix, althought they overlap).

Comment: How does this work in terms of the OS? (Or machine code) Does it just copy 8 bits from the top of the stack, where I assume the C++ program pushes back 4 lots of 8 bits at the start of execution?

Comment: The return value is `int`. The C++ and C standard says NOTHING of how return values are returned (but typically it is in a register). As long as the OS maintains consistency as to the returned value and the call to `main` [which by the way is typically NOT where the application starts as such, there is typically some stuff that happens before that, such as setting up `stdin`, `stdout`, `cin`, `cout`, and many other things that needs to happen "before your program starts".]

Comment: *"but legal values for exit codes are only 0-255"* Legal according to whom?

Comment: related: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html