# What is the $? (dollar question mark) variable in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm trying to learn shell scripting, and I need to understand someone else's code. What is the `$?` variable hold? I can't Google search the answer because they block punctuation characters.

Comment: A good google search turns out to be "bash dollar question mark"

Comment: SymbolHound works well for searches involving special characters. Example: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%24%3F

Comment: `info bash` also works, but unfortunately you can't just search for "$?", since the documentation omits the `$`. Go to the "Special Parameters" section (3.4.2 as of version 4.2) or search for backtick-`\$'` (you have to escape the `?` because the search term is a regular expression). (I'm sure there's a way to put a literal backtick in a comment.)

Comment: That moment when googling "bash dollar question mark" brings this SO Question as first result. Don't blame us.

Comment: @KeithThompson You probably know this by now, but you can escape it with `\\` (so you end up writing `\\\`` to get the backtick) (and `\\\\\\\`` to get what I just wrote)

Answer (score 341, accepted):

`$?` is used to find the return value of the last executed command.
Try the following in the shell:

```
ls somefile
echo $?
```

If `somefile` exists (regardless whether it is a file or directory), you will get the return value thrown by the `ls` command, which should be `0` (default "success" return value). If it doesn't exist, you should get a number other then 0. The exact number depends on the program.

For many programs you can find the numbers and their meaning in the corresponding man page. These will usually be described as "exit status" and may have their own section.

Comment: Not just error code. It's the returned status code of any command.

Comment: If the file doesn't exist, the return value is `2`

Comment: if command not found 127 returns

Comment: So `man $?` is your friend to get the exit status. Invoking `((1==2));echo $?` returns 1 in bash.

Comment: if any curious onlooker is interested in the source on **bash** _docs_, it's [here: **special parameters**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_003f)

Answer (score 52):

That is the exit status of the last executed function/program/command. Refer to:

- [exit / exit status @ tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html#EXSREF)
- [Special Shell Variables @ tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22006)
- [Special Characters @ tlpd.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html)

Answer (score 22):

A return value of the previously executed process.

> 10.4 Getting the return value of a program
>
> In bash, the return value of a program is stored in a special variable
>   called $?.
>
> This illustrates how to capture the return value of a program, I
>   assume that the directory dada does not exist. (This was also
>   suggested by mike)
>
> ```
>         #!/bin/bash
>         cd /dada &> /dev/null
>         echo rv: $?
>         cd $(pwd) &> /dev/null
>         echo rv: $?
> ```

See [Bash Programming Manual](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-10.html#ss10.4) for more details.

Comment: For a moment, I thought `rv:` was some sort of old style options list, but it turns out just to be text which is echoed.

Answer (score 22):

**Minimal POSIX C exit status example**

To understand `$?`, you must first understand the concept of process exit status which is defined [by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755). In Linux:

- when a process calls the `exit` system call, the kernel stores the value passed to the system call (an `int`) even after the process dies.

  The exit system call is called by the `exit()` ANSI C function, and indirectly when you do `return` from `main`.
- the process that called the exiting child process (Bash), often with `fork` + `exec`, can retrieve the exit status of the child with the `wait` system call

Consider the Bash code:

```
$ false
$ echo $?
1
```

The C "equivalent" is:

false.c

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */

int main(void) {
    exit(1);
}
```

bash.c

```
#include <unistd.h> /* execl */
#include <stdlib.h> /* fork */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* wait, WEXITSTATUS */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */

int main(void) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        /* Call false. */
        execl("./false", "./false", (char *)NULL);
    }
    int status;
    /* Wait for a child to finish. */
    wait(&status);
    /* Status encodes multiple fields,
     * we need WEXITSTATUS to get the exit status:
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659616/returning-exit-code-from-child
     **/
    printf("$? = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o bash bash.c
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o false false.c
./bash
```

Output:

```
$? = 1
```

In Bash, when you hit enter, a fork + exec + wait happens like above, and bash then sets `$?` to the exit status of the forked process.

Note: for built-in commands like `echo`, a process need not be spawned, and Bash just sets `$?` to 0 to simulate an external process.

**Standards and documentation**

POSIX 7 2.5.2 "Special Parameters" http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02 :

> ? Expands to the decimal exit status of the most recent pipeline (see Pipelines).

`man bash` "Special Parameters":

> The shell treats several parameters specially.  These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed. [...]
>
> ? Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

ANSI C and POSIX then recommend that:

- `0` means the program was successful
- other values: the program failed somehow.

  The exact value could indicate the type of failure.

  ANSI C does not define the meaning of any vaues, and POSIX specifies  values larger than 125:  [What is the meaning of "POSIX"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/i-never-really-understood-what-is-posix/31865755#31865755)

**Bash uses exit status for `if`**

In Bash, we often use the exit status `$?` implicitly to control `if` statements as in:

```
if true; then
  :
fi
```

where `true` is a program that just returns 0.

The above is equivalent to:

```
true
result=$?
if [ $result = 0 ]; then
  :
fi
```

And in:

```
if [ 1 = 1 ]; then
  :
fi
```

`[` is just an program with a weird name (and Bash built-in that behaves like it), and `1 = 1 ]` its arguments, see also: [Difference between single and double square brackets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash/31366734#31366734)

Answer (score 12):

$? is the result (exit code) of the last executed command.

Answer (score 6):

It is the returned error code of the last executed command. 0 = success

Answer (score 5):

`$?` is the exit status of a command, such that you can daisy-chain a series of commands.

**Example**

```
command1 && command2 && command3
```

`command2` will run if `command1's` `$?` yields a `success (0)` and `command3` will execute if `$?` of `command2` will yield a `success`

Answer (score 3):

The exit code of the last command ran.

Answer (score 3):

It is well suited for debugging in case your script exit if `set -e` is used. For example, put  `echo $?` after the command that cause it to exit and see the returned error value.