# What is wrong with my guessing game program?

Tags: bash

So yes I am doing this for school but I have most of the script written. I don't know what's going on with it, maybe a syntax error but it keeps messing up(or I do).

The first issue is that it keeps posting the number that you are trying to guess and it says no file or directory(I didn't think I was calling for such things). The 86 is the current random number.

```
./random: line 14: 86: No such file or directory
```

The second issue is that the program is telling me guesses are always too low(I can also get them to always be too high)

```
 I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Your guess:6

./random: line 14: 86: No such file or directory
Sorry, your guess is too low. New guess:87

./random: line 14: 86: No such file or directory
Sorry, your guess is too low. New guess:
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash


n1=$[($RANDOM % 100) +1]
guesses=1
echo -n "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Your guess:"

while read n2; do

if   [ $n2 = $n1 ]; then
break;  
else
echo    
if [ $n2 < $n1 ]; then 
echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too high. New guess:"
elif [ $n2 > $n1]; then
echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too low. New guess:"
fi      
fi
guesses=$((guesses+1))

done
echo
echo "Good job! It took you $guesses guesses to get the right number."
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems you forgot the code.

Comment: ..and you expect us to magically figure out what your code is?

Comment: I think the solution is pretty simple, whatever file or directory you are referencing is not there, or you are referencing it wrong.

Comment: The problem is there is no such file or directory.  I think the file missing is your code

Comment: The problem is that your telepathy is out of tune. Just like you and your program can't read a number from someone's mind, we can't read code from yours.

Comment: Hey sorry I forgot to post that....

Comment: Try using `[[` instead of `[`.  Try using `-gt` instead of `>`.  Try using `-lt` instead of `<`. Try using `-eq` instead of `=`

Comment: It should be updated now

Comment: Also you have your `<` and `>` incorrectly swapped

Comment: Is that a bash script ?  < and > are the symbols for input and output redirection in that language, if I'm not mistaken.  Credits to digital trauma.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma When I change the > and < it says guess too high. When I change the [ to [[ it says:     I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Your guess:./random: line 16: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
./random: line 16: syntax error near `;'
./random: line 16: `elif [[ $n2 < $n1]]; then'

Comment: Also in the elif, you need a space between `$n1` and `]]`.  I've made the edits I suggested and it seems to work correctly.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Nice catch on the space. I switched that and the < and > to -gt and -lt and it seems to work just fine. Post it as an answer and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer as described in the comments above:

```
#!/bin/bash


n1=$[($RANDOM % 100) +1]
guesses=1
echo -n "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100. Your guess:"

while read n2; do

if   [[ $n2 -eq $n1 ]]; then
break;  
else
echo    
if [[ $n2 -gt $n1 ]]; then 
echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too high. New guess:"
elif [[ $n2 -lt $n1 ]]; then
echo -n "Sorry, your guess is too low. New guess:"
fi      
fi
guesses=$((guesses+1))

done
echo
echo "Good job! It took you $guesses guesses to get the right number."
```

In general you need to pay attention to the error messages bash is giving you:

```
./random: line 14: 86: No such file or directory
```

Line 14 is:

```
if [ $n2 < $n1 ]; then
```

and we know $n1 is 86 in this case.  So this means the script is attempting to run `86` as if it were a command, hence the file not found error.  Why is bash doing this?  Well its probably interpreting `<` as a redirection instead of a greater-than operator.  So there is something wrong with the if conditional syntax.  Time to dig out the manuals http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs

Comment: The [[ still break the code but it works if you just have a single [.

Comment: Oops, I also forgot to add the space between `$n1` and `]]` in the elif.  Edited... now it works with `[[` `]]` as expected.

Comment: More reading on the differences between `[` and `[[`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/bash-if-difference-between-square-brackets-and-double-square-brackets