# Getting "command not found" error while comparing two strings in Bash

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, syntax, compare

My whole script is currently this:

```
#!/bin/sh   
clear;   
blanko="";   
# Dummy-Variablen
variable=Testvariable;   
if [[$variable == $blanko]];
then   
  echo "Nichts da!"   
else   
  echo $variable   
fi
```

and if I enter

```
TestSelect.sh
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/TestSelect.sh: line 6: [[Testvariable: command not found   
Testvariable
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Tip for the future: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) will automatically point out this and other basic issues.

Comment: Another pointer: you only need a statement-terminating `;` if you're putting _multiple_ statements on a single line.

Comment: You need spaces between `[[` and `$variable` and `$blanko` and `]]`

Comment: Other question is about use of [ which is an external utility in Unix but this is different problem

Comment: Double check that you don't have a **non breaking space** instead of a regular space. I often typo a nbsp instead of a space and cause this to fail in a hard-to-understand/debug way.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

This is problem:

```
if [[$variable == $blanko]];
```

Spaces are required inside square brackets, use it like this:

```
[[ "$variable" == "$blanko" ]] && echo "Nichts da!" || echo "$variable"
```

Comment: Note, however, that there's no need to double-quote the variable references (even if the values have embedded spaces).

Comment: @mklement0: Just for good practice I always quote them, may not be always needed.

Comment: @mklement0 original it was a testvariable cause i didn't know for sure if I correctly described an empty string, to be honest.

Comment: @anubhava: Certainly a safe approach - when what shell expansions take place is not easy to remember; when in doubt, `man bash` describes them (some digging required).

Comment: @EpsilonAlpha: English has the same saying: "[I] cannot see the forest for the trees".

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks, very correctly put. Quoting most of the times will be safe.

Comment: but why do we need spaces in the first place like this?

Comment: @quantum231: That is bash syntax

Comment: ok, but why do we get a "command not found" error in place of "syntax" error?

Comment: Because bash interprets that as a command in the absence of right syntax

Comment: And remember **non breaking space** is not the same as a space for this, even if they look 100% identical.

Answer (score 38):

On a related note, spaces are required around `[ ]` as well:

```
if [ "$variable" = "$blanko" ]; then
  # more code here
fi
```

Note that variables do need to be enclosed in double quotes inside `[ ]` to prevent word splitting and globbing.  Double quotes also help when either of the variables being compared is not set - shell will throw a syntax error otherwise.

Look at the following post to understand why we need spaces around `[ ]`:

- [Why should there be a space after '[' and before ']' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash)

Another related post that talks about other syntax elements that need spaces as well:

- [Why is whitespace sometimes needed around metacharacters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186724/why-is-whitespace-sometimes-needed-around-metacharacters)

Finally, this post talks about the difference between `[[ ]]` and `[ ]`:

- [Difference between single and double square brackets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash)

---

Related:

- [“0: command not found” in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42558479/6862601)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `#!/bin/bash` on tope of script if you are using bash scripting like: `if [[ $partition == "/dev/sda2" ]]; then` to compare string and run script with `./scriptname.sh` or `bash scriptname.sh`

Answer (score -1):

If your script runs on your local with `/bin/bash` but not on your container with `sh`, then consider adding bash to your container by `apk add --no-cache bash`.