# How can I test if a variable contains a string in a bash script without getting the "command not found" error?

Tags: bash, shell, string-comparison

I keep getting a "command not found" error after checking a variable for the substring `.txt`.

Here's a simple version of my script.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
if [["$1" == *.txt]]
    then
    echo $1
fi
```

Result:

```
> ./myscript.sh argument.txt
./myscript.sh: line 2: [[argument.txt: command not found]]
```

Comment: #meta, is it advisable to delete questions like these? I obviously didn't know it was a simple typo issue when I wrote the question.  Is it better to leave this up for others to discover the mistake themselves or delete the question entirely.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733437/if-compare-strings-get-a-command-not-found-error which seems like a much worse 'question' than this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of a space needed around the brackets `[[` and `]]`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ "$1" == *.txt ]]
    then
    echo $1
fi
```

That is, instead of:

```
if [["$1" == *.txt]]
```

use

```
if [[ "$1" == *.txt ]]
```

Comment: Of course. I tried right away but it was too soon.