# Super Simple bash If (variable > integer) treating (variable as a command

Tags: bash

I feel like this should be really simple but I can't get past this step.

```
$num = 5
if [$num > 2]; then echo greater; fi
```

the problem is, I keep getting `[5: command not found`.

Why is it not evaluating the `if [ test ]` block correctly? It's like the shell forgot about the `if` and just moved on to "hey, `[5 > 2` does not look like a command, I can't find `[5`"... but `[5` isn't a command, it's part of the `if` test block?

I have tried using different brackets and using `-gt` instead of `>`. The problem is bash doesn't actually ever do the test. For some reason it ignores `if`.

Comment: I think you need to a space in between `[` and `]`, i.e. `if [ $num > 2 ]; then` ...

Comment: That's exactly it. I just posted an answer I found too. I knew it would be something fiddly. Cheers!

Comment: To mark a question as solved, instead of editing the subject, please mark an answer as accepted (by clicking the green checkmark to its left).

Comment: The thing that goes after `if` *is* a command. Could be any valid command (or even series of commands separated by line breaks or semicolons), it just happens that the `[` command (which is actually another name for the `test` command) is really common in `if` statements. But you can use any other command as the `if` test, and you can use `[` anyplace you'd use any other command.

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to find the answer:
[if compare strings get a "command not found"-Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733437/if-compare-strings-get-a-command-not-found-error)

really unexpected, there needs to be a space between the [ brackets and the variable.

I would never have guessed.

Comment: Instead of guessing, try [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net).