# "[0: command not found" in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I am trying to get the array in the while-loop and need to update the value in array too.

Below is my code what I have tried. I get this error `[0: command not found`

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [$i -le "{#myarray[@]}" ]
do 
    echo "Welcome $i times"
    i= $(($i+1)))
done
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I found Greg's Wiki to be very helpful in learning bash: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Need a space after `[` and no space before or after `=` in the assignment. `$(($i+1)))` would try to execute the output of the `((...))` expression and I am sure that's not what you want. Also, you are missing a `$` before the array name.

With these things corrected, your while loop would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while [ "$i" -le "${#myarray[@]}" ]
do 
  echo "Welcome $i times"
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

- `i=$((i + 1))` can also be written as `((i++))`
- it is always better to enclose variables in double quotes inside `[ ... ]`
- check your script through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) - you can catch most basic issues there

---

See also:

- [Why should there be a space after '[' and before ']' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash)
- [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/how-to-use-double-or-single-brackets-parentheses-curly-braces)
- [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment)
- [Using [ ] vs [[ ]] in a Bash if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825114/6862601)

Comment: Great answer to an iffy question (broad enough to be split into multiple dupes, as you've pointed out).

Comment: this was the only thing stopping my startup script from working in my .bashrc file, thanks!