# Bash error [: missing `]' when checking if file exists

Tags: bash, syntax

I am getting the error `[: missing` ]'` when running the below line in bash.

```
if [ ! -f "$file"]; then
    echo "File not found!"
fi
```

Comment: This is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42558479/6862601 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9581064/6862601

Comment: @codeforester It was a similar answer but I believe the question was very different. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: The questions are similar to yours because it is about the misunderstanding of `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
[ ! -f "$file"]
```

to

```
[ ! -f "$file" ]
```

Change summary: added space before `]`