# Programme Showing "Command not found"

Tags: bash, shell

The Code Below showing "Command not found " at line 12.I have tried many way but it did not fix.What is the problem?Can anyone explain?

```
#!bin/bash
echo "How many number do you want to input?"
read numbers
echo "Give your input seperated by enter"
array=()
for (( i = 0 ; i < $numbers ; i=$i+1 ));
do
    read num;
    array+=($num);
done
for (( j = 0 ; j < $numbers-1 ; j=$j+1 ));
do
    if ["${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$j+1]}"];
    then
        tempo=${array[$j]};
        array[$j]=${array[$j+1]};
        array[$j+1]=$temp;
    fi
done

for (( i = 0 ; i < $numbers ; i=$i+1 )); 
do 
    echo ${array[$i]};
done
```

Comment: You forgot to describe your problem, add expected and actual output, and ask a question.

Comment: You're missing a `/` in your shebang, it should be `#!/bin/bash`. (I had added that as an answer but then noticed you said the error was thrown at line 12, so I guess that's not your main problem)

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sorry for the trouble.I have added details.Can you help me?

Comment: @Aaron I have changed this.But It do not stop showing the same error.

Comment: You also need to have spaces inside your `[ ... ]` tests : `if [ "${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$j+1]}" ];`. I ran your code in ideone.com with my suggestions included and that was the next part to fail. You should include the whole error message next time : even if the `[9` part in `line 13: [9: command not found` means nothing to you, it's a huge hint about what's going wrong.

Comment: I suggest checking your code with http://www.shellcheck.net/ which would probably indicate all these problems without the need to wait for a back-and-forth on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Aaron Within `(( ))`, you can have spaces around `=`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, I removed my incorrect comment.

Comment: This really should be run through shellcheck, as Aaron said, and most syntax errors would be pointed out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if compare strings get a "command not found"-Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733437/if-compare-strings-get-a-command-not-found-error)

Answer (score 1):

Copy-pasting your original code into [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) lends this useful result :

```
Line 13:
    if ["${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$j+1]}"];
    ^-- SC1009: The mentioned parser error was in this if expression.
       ^-- SC1035: You need a space after the [ and before the ].
       ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression.
                                            ^-- SC1020: You need a space before the ].
                                            ^-- SC1072: Missing space before ]. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

This is your first problem, a syntax error that makes `bash` parse `[` and whatever follows it once expanded as a single command, which it fails to find.

Once fixed, shellcheck will be able to bring up many other problems, such as defining a `tempo` variable then referencing an undefined `temp` variable afterwards.

Some of the tips it produces probably aren't relevant to your use-case (such as `read` mangling backslashes). It's up to you to apply them or not, but it's always a good thing to know the shortcomings of the commands you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with your spaces in BASH. Line 12 should read:

```
 if [ "${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$j+1]}" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all spaces in operations like this: `j = 0`. It must be: `j=0`

In bash a variable assignment has the syntax: `name=[value]`. You cannot put unquoted spaces around the `=` because bash would not interpret this as the assignment you intend. Bash treats most lists of words as a command with parameters.

And add spaces in this line `if ["${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$j+1]}"];`. it must be `if [ "${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$j+1]}" ];`. You can read about spaces more here: [Why should there be a space after '[' and before ']' in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581064/why-should-there-be-a-space-after-and-before-in-bash)

Comment: Add spacef before `]` and after `[` in `["${array[$j]}" -gt "${array[$j+1]}"];`

Comment: Are you saying there must not be spaces in `i = 0` within `(( ))`? Because there can be.