# "command not found" error when using a variable

Tags: bash

I have been trying to fix an error
the error says "your_input command not found" even though a variable is not a command

```sh
#/bin/bash

echo "Hello, World!!"
echo "Press enter to exit."
read your_input
if [your_input == ""]
then
    echo "Bye!!"
else
    echo "You typed $your_input anyway. Bye!!"
fi
```

Edit:
Thank you to costaparas for telling me to use `[ "$your_input" == "" ]`

Comment: You need whitespace - and a `$` sign on the variable: `[your_input == ""]` => `[ "$your_input" == "" ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "command not found" error while comparing two strings in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733437/getting-command-not-found-error-while-comparing-two-strings-in-bash)

Comment: Btw the double quotes around the variable are crucial - the user could type arbitrary content, including for instance whitespaces and other shell metacharacters

Comment: In bash (as opposed to sh) you can also use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` and then you don't need the double quotes.

Comment: I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) -- it's good at spotting common mistakes like this.