# simple string comparison in bash

Tags: bash

I'm looking to get the number of subdirectories within a directory and compare that with a predefined number.

Ex:

```
cd /Applications/
x=echo ls -d */ | wc -l | sed 's/^ *//g'
y="52"

if [ "$x" == "$y" ]; then
    echo "equal"
else
    echo "not equal"
fi
```

It will give me a number for x (52 in my case), but will always say "not equal". What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, it will not give you a number.

Comment: consider using the [[ ]] - double-square-bracket form of predicates, unless you need compatibility with shells which don't have this extension, for the reasons given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/bash-if-difference-between-square-brackets-and-double-square-brackets

Comment: I do know this will not give me a number per se, but I am comparing two strings; unless I'm missing something? I have tried double-square brackets as well unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

For bash, do this:

```
cd /Applications/
dirs=( */ )   # dirs is an array with the names of directories here
if (( ${#dirs[@]} == $y )); then
    echo "equal"
else
    echo "not equal"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
x=echo ls -d */ | wc -l | sed 's/^ *//g'
```

with:

```
x="$(ls -d */ | wc -l | sed 's/^ *//g')"
```

**Explanation:**  When you write `x=echo ls -d */ ...`, bash thinks that you mean to temporarily set the the variable `x` to a value of "echo" and then run the `ls` command.  You, instead, want to run the command `s -d */ | wc -l | sed 's/^ *//g'` and save the output in x.  The construct `x=$(...)` tells bash to execute whatever was in the parens and assign the output to `x`.

**Also,** bash's `[` command does not accept `==`.  Use `=` for string comparison.  However, you really want mathematical comparison. So use '-eq':

```
  if [ "$x" -eq "$y" ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I notice that it is no longer printing the value for x, but it's still not evaluating my comparison properly. 52 == 52 is showing not equal. Unless I'm still missing something?

Comment: I originally started with 'eq' and then '=', but both result in not equal. Thanks again.