# How to test strings for lexicographic less than or equal in Bash?

Tags: bash

In Bash, is there a simple way to test if one string is lexicographically less than or equal to another?

I know you can do:

```
if [[ "a" < "b" ]]
```

for testing strict inequality, or

```
if [[ 1 -le 1 ]]
```

for numbers. But `-le` doesn't seem to work with strings, and using `<=` gives a syntax error.

Comment: Use `compare` to test for this.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison On my Debian `compare` is an ImageMagick command (for image processing/diffing).

Comment: @bryn gotta "love" those ultra generic ImageMagick command names :-)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just negate the greater than test:

```
if [[ ! "a" > "b" ]]
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to use `||` with an additional condition instead of `<=`:

```
[[ "$a" < "$b" || "$a" == "$b" ]]
```

Comment: Is there any POSIX way?

Comment: Use `[ ! "$a" -gt "$b" ]` in POSIX

Comment: Isn't `-gt` for integers only?

Comment: @CiroSantilli烏坎事件2016六四事件法轮功 works for me: `test "5" -gt "6" ; echo $?` —> 1, and `test "7" -gt "6" ; echo $?` —> 0

Comment: @KajMagnus You're testing with integers, not arbitrary strings. `test "abc" -gt "xyz" ; echo $?` --> "-bash: test: abc: integer expression expected". Also, string comparison order is different: as integers, "10" is greater than "9", but as strings it's the other way around because "1" comes before "9" in lexical sorting order.

Comment: @ciro-santilli I added a new answer with POSIX syntax

Answer (score 3):

You can flip the comparison and sign around and test negatively:

```
$ a="abc"
$ b="abc"
$ if ! [[ "$b" > "$a" ]] ; then  echo "a <= b" ; fi
a <= b
```

If you want collating sequence of "A" then "a" then "B"... use:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

Answer (score 3):

**`expr` POSIX method**

I believe `[ a < b ]` is a Bash extension. The best POSIX method I could find was this as documented at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html:

```
expr abc \< acb >/dev/null || echo fail
! expr abc \< aac >/dev/null || echo fail
```

or with slightly worse golfing and a subshell:

```
[ "$(expr abc \< acb)" = 1 ] || echo fail
[ "$(expr abc \< aac)" = 0 ] || echo fail
```

But because `expr \<` is completely insane and:

- automatically determines is something is an integer or not to choose numerical vs lexicographical comparison, e.g. `expr 2 \< 10` is `1`
- has undefined behaviour for magic keywords `length`, `substr`, `index` and `match`

you generally want to add a trash `x` to force your variable to be a non-reserved string as in:

```
x1=aac
x2=abc
x3=acb
expr x"$x2" \< x"$x3" >/dev/null || echo fail
! expr x"$x2" \< x"$x1" >/dev/null || echo fail
```

and so for less than or equal I'd just:

```
expr x"$x1" \< x"$x2" >/dev/null || [ "$x1" = "$x2" ] || echo fail
```

**`sort` POSIX workaround**

Just for fun, use `expr` instead.

Not infinitely robust to strings with newlines, but when is it ever when dealing with shell scripts?

```
string_lte() (
  s="$(printf "${1}\n${2}")"
  [ "$(printf '%s' "$s" | sort)" = "$s" ]
)
string_lte abc adc || echo fail
string_lte adc adc || echo fail
string_lte afc adc && echo fail
```

Comment: `sort -c` is in POSIX, so we can have `string_lte() { printf '%s\n' "$1" "$2" | sort -c }`.  Sadly `sort -z` isn't portable, but if you have it, we can use `\0` in place of `\n` to get a newline-safe comparison.  (N.B. your `printf` is broken if either argument contains `%`!)

Comment: BTW, `if command; then exit 0; else exit 1; fi` can generally be replaced by `command; exit` (or `command || false; exit` if we really care about replacing all failure statuses by 1) - and the `exit` isn't necessary at end of subshell.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the Bash syntax, see the answers from @anubhava and @gordon-davisson. With POSIX syntax you have two options (note the necessary backslashes!):

using the `-o` operator (OR):

```
[ "$a" \< "$b" -o "$a" = "$b" ] && echo "'$a' LTE '$b'" || echo "'$a' GT '$b'"
```

or using negation:

```
[ ! "$a" \> "$b" ] && echo "'$a' LTE '$b'" || echo "'$a' GT '$b'"
```

I prefer the first variant, because imho it's more readable.

Comment: I think it is an extension still. Or can you find a clear POSIX quote? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html seems to even mention it on the rationale: "Some additional primaries newly invented or from the KornShell appeared in an early proposal as part of the conditional command ([[]]): s1 > s2, s1 < s2, str = pattern, str != pattern, f1 -nt f2, f1 -ot f2, and f1 -ef f2. They were not carried forward into the test utility [...]".

Comment: See here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128 But yes, it's marked `[OB XSI]`: OB = Obsolescent [Option End]
The functionality described may be removed in a future version of this volume of POSIX.1-2017. Strictly Conforming POSIX Applications and Strictly Conforming XSI Applications shall not use obsolescent features.

Comment: `XSI`= The functionality described is part of the X/Open Systems Interfaces option. Functionality marked XSI is an extension to the ISO C standard. Application developers may confidently make use of such extensions on all systems supporting the X/Open System Interfaces option. I will stick with Bash syntax in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I use python: 's1="abc"; s2="cde"; if /usr/bin/python -c "exit('$s1'<'$s2')" ; then echo "s1>=s2" ; else echo "s1<s2" ; fi
`

Comment: That gets broken when either argument contains `'`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).