# how to compare current date and date in file if is equal or greater

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare if today's date is greater than or equal to the date `2023-09-18` (YYYY-MM-DD), but it seems `>=` (this throws errors) and `-ge` operators are not for comparing dates (I tried with both one `[]` and two `[[]]` but have the same error and result).

```
if [[ "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -ge "2023-09-18" ]]
then
    echo "today is equal or greater than 2023-09-18."
else
    echo "today is before 2023-09-18."
fi
```

When I run this, I get this error message:

```
-bash: [[: 2023-09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
today is before 2023-09-18.
```

How can I compare the date if is equal or greater than today?

Comment: `-ge` is only for arithmetic compare. for strings use `>` or `<`.

Comment: @pynexj but they don't compare equal or greater.

Comment: Have a look at the bash man-page, section _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSION_. You will see that there is no _greater or equal_ for strings. You can test for _greater_  and for _equality_ separately.

Comment: the suggested duplicate answer fails to address `<=` or `>=` and user1934428's comment is correct but incomplete; this [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294867) is a better fit fo this question (see answers by GordonDavisson and anubhava for two approaches for implementing `<=` and `>=`)