# Bash Syntax error in conditional expression

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a simple bash script that will iterate through a text file containing IP addresses,
ping them one time, and see if they are alive or not.

This is my work so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(cat ips.txt); do
if [[ "1" ==  "$(ping -c 1 $ip | grep 'packets transmitted' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)"]]
echo $ip
fi
done
```

Any Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the error which you are getting ?

Comment: You need a space before the final `]]`. And you're missing the `then` after that (and if the `then` is on the same line, you'll need a `;` before it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ip in $(cat ips.txt); do
if [ "1" ==  "$(ping -c 1 $ip | grep 'packets transmitted' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)" ]; then
    echo $ip
fi
done
```

You needed the `; then` after the `if [ ... ]` statement (same thing goes for `elif`, not `else`), and a space between the last bracket of the statement and the statement's contents. Also this appears to work fine with just single brackets, and this may be more portable (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13542854/2943276)).

Works on Bash 4.2.47

Comment: `for ip in $(cat ips.txt)` is, by the way, generally deprecated as a way to loop over contents of a file. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use a newline instead of `;` if you like, but you always need the `then` keyword.

```
if [ "1" ==  "$(ping -c 1 $ip | grep 'packets transmitted' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)" ]
then echo $ip
fi

# or

if [ "1" ==  "$(ping -c 1 $ip | grep 'packets transmitted' | cut -d ' ' -f 4)" ]
then
    echo $ip
fi
```