# Find missing files by their number?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop, command

I have a big list of ordered files with names like this

```
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_6.txt
file_7.txt
file_8.txt
file_10.txt
```

In this case it is easy to see that files: `file_4.txt`,`file_5.txt` and `file_9.txt` are missing, but if i have a big list how can i find the missing files? i am just learning bash so i just know some simple examples. like this

```
for i in $(seq 1 1000) ;

do  
  if [i not in *.txt];  then                                                                                                     
  echo $i;

done
```

But this doesnt even work unless i erase the `if [i not in *.txt];then` line
so it just writes all the numbers between 1 and 1000.
I hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If they are in a file then this should work

```
awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+)/,a){a[1]>max&&max=a[1];b[a[1]]++}
     END{for(i=1;i<max;i++)if(!b[i])print "file_"i".txt"}' file
```

---

#### Output

```
file_4.txt
file_5.txt
file_9.txt
```

Comment: They are in a directory

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from @user4453924 really helped me out. It does not have to be in a file, just pipe output from ls into his awk command, and you should be fine:

```
ls *.txt | awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+)/,a){a[1]>max&&max=a[1];b[a[1]]++}
 END{for(i=1;i<max;i++)if(!b[i])print "file_"i".txt"}'
```

Outputs:

```
file_4.txt
file_5.txt
file_9.txt
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to do it in a two step fashion, it would be quite simple to pipe the output from ls into a file, and then use his command directly on the file, as it is:

```
ls *.txt > filelist.txt
awk 'match($0,/([0-9]+)/,a){a[1]>max&&max=a[1];b[a[1]]++}
 END{for(i=1;i<max;i++)if(!b[i])print "file_"i".txt"}' filelist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by

```
## TODO: You need to change the following path:
THELIST=/path/to/input-file

for i in $(seq 1 10); 
do 
  FOUND=`grep "file_$i.txt" "$THELIST"` #look for file $i in $THELIST
                                        #Note: double quotes were placed around $THELIST 
                                        #      in case there is whitespace in the filename 

  [[ "$FOUND" == "" ]] && echo $i     #if what you found is empty, then output $i
done
```

---

- You can find info about `[[ ... ]]`  here: [What is the difference between single and double square brackets in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/bash-if-difference-between-square-brackets-and-double-)
  square-brackets

Comment: Huh? Your `find` is looking in the filesystem, but the OP wants to look in a *list of files in a text file* - no filesystem access required... you probably want `grep` in the list.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I wasn't to sure what OP was looking for ..this input was not here before ;)

Comment: Consider surrounding `$THELIST` with double quotes in case there is a space in the filename.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help but i tryed this but it returns every $i , every number between 1 and 10