# What does `[[ -e ~/.profile ]] ` mean in zsh shell?

Tags: shell, sh, zsh, bash

I wanted to make zsh load `~/.profile`  at login. And I found this [zsh-not-hitting-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/187639/)

Gilles's answers adding `emulate sh -c '. ~/.profile'` in `~/.zprofle`
does work.

But I wonder why Frank Terbeck make an addition to it:

`[[ -e ~/.profile ]] && emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile'`

I am not very familiar with linux shell so I don't understand what he says:

> And it's only active during the source. So you do not have to save the current option state in order to replay it again after sourcing.

1. only active during the source? I need `~/.profile` always need to be source , I can't get the meaning, because `emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile` simply works everytime I logined.
2. save the current option state in order to replay? what is the option state, why I need to replay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[ -e ~/.profile ]]` simply tests whether the file `~/.profile` exists. This way you won't get an error doing `source ~/.profile` if the file isn't there.

"only active during the source" means that the `-c` option that you give to the `emulate` command doesn't change the options to the original shell process. It just uses that temporarily during the emulation of the `source` command.

Comment: Thanks, by searching `bash check file exist` I understand `-e ~/.profile` usage , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash  tell me what is the double square brackets mean.

Comment: The original Bourne shell had a very limited external utility called `[` aka `test`; subsequent shells (predominantly) chose a similarly "syntax-looking" but different construct for introducing new built-in functionality, to preserve backwards compatibility but introduce new behavior.

Comment: @tripleee That's explained in the question he linked to.

Comment: Huh? I don't see an explanation of this syntax there.  (Though he also posted the same *comment* there, too; flagged as too chatty.)

Comment: @tripleee The top answer there says **Double [[]] are an extension to the standard [] and are supported by bash and other shells**

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was looking at the SuperUser link in the question.