# Getting an Syntax Error Of an Official Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to install doconce with this script
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hplgit/doconce/master/doc/src/manual/install_doconce.sh
But if I try to run it, I get an Syntax error `install_doconce.sh: 14: install_doconce.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected`
How can i fix this?

Comment: How do you invoke the script? Are you sure you are using the correct shell (bash)?

Comment: sh install_doconce.sh under debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are running the script using a specific interpreter, such as `mysh install_doconce.sh`. You should instead run it *directly*, as in `./install_doconce.sh`.

Comment: sort of i guess.. tried it with `sh install_doconce.sh`, where I got this error. With `bash install_doconce.sh` it seems to work

Comment: I would still suggest running shell scripts directly, as suggested. Then you aren't second guessing which shell it was developed for…

Comment: @Barsch If you use `./install_doonce.sh`, it will run with the interpreter that it is meant for. Please do that instead of trying interpreters until you find one that works. You were really lucky that you only got a syntax error.