# Not found when running file

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have the executable transactor in the current directory which can be seen by ls.

```
/datomic-pro-1.0.6316/bin # ls -lah transactor
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         698 Aug  1 03:10 transactor
```

But when I run it like ./transactor, I get:

```
sh: ./transactor: not found
```

How to fix this?

Comment: What is the `transactor` file? A binary, or a script (in which case what's its shebang line), or what? Also, what OS and shell are you using?

Comment: It's a script #!/bin/bash. Ah, so because I'm running sh.

Comment: Are you sure the file name is exactly `transactor`? No spaces added at the end? If yes try `chmod +x transactor` to enable its executable permission flag. Then `./transactor`. But I doubt it is this, the error message would be different, something like `sh: ./transactor: Permission denied`. So, my first bet is that the file is not exactly `transactor`. What do you see if you type `ls -b transactor*`? Is there a backslash at the end of the output?

Comment: You should be able to run a bash script from plain sh, but does /bin/bash actually exist on your system? (A shebang pointing to a nonexistent interpreter can give errors like this.) Also, are there any weird/nonprinting/invisible characters in the shebang line? (You can check by printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -vt transactor | head`)

Answer (score 0):

The normal way of running a script is:

```
sh transactor
```

There are cases where "`.`" is not recognised, but I don't know exactly which they are.

Comment: Using `./scriptname` is generally better than using `sh`, because it allows the shebang line to control which interpreter is used to run the script. If it's a bash script, `sh` might not support any bash extensions it uses. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42879524/getting-an-syntax-error-of-an-official-shell-script) is an example.