# Why does the script launched through Crontab behave differently?

Tags: bash, cron

I have .sh script in UbuntuServer (VM):

```
response=$(curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth 9f65dd6onr07vhpdqblbiix5rl0tch' -X GET 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/127060528' | jq -r '.stream');
now=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T");
echo "$now" >> log.txt;
echo "$response" >> log.txt;
if [[ "$response" == "null" ]]
then
  echo "ZERO"
else
  streamlink -o "dump/stream_$now.mp3" twitch.tv/mahetirecords/clip/FreezingEncouragingCougarSuperVinlin audio
  echo "STREAM"
fi
```

When I run the script through the bash, the **THEN**-way is triggered.
When I run the script through crontab, the **ELSE**-way is triggered.
WHY?

Crontab -e:

```
* * * * * /home/chesterlife/twitch-interceptor/script.sh
```

If the stream is offline, then "$response" return **null**. This is text-null because `var=""; if [ "$var" == "$response" ]; then echo "true"; else echo "false"; fi` return **false**

Any ideas?

Comment: Often, the reason for a script behaving differently when run by cron compared to run by you in the shell is the environment — the job run through cron doesn't go through your profile (etc) to set the environment the way your interactive sessions get the environment set.  This can be a big factor.

Comment: Do you include a shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) line at the top of the script?  That may ensure that the script is run by Bash rather than `sh`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default crontab executes using `sh` shell. You can change it to `bash` using the information from the link below:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Also read this Stack Overflow question about [the difference between `[` and `[[` in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash)

While `[` is POSIX, `[[` is only supported by some shells including `bash`.

Comment: The script should have a proper shebang (this is basic good practice), but it could also easily be rewritten to run in a basic shell by switching to a single-bracket test command (and a single `=` for equality): `if [ "$response" = "null" ]`. Personally, I'd do both.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a shebang in the script beginning, eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Also, you should add your current user's path (obtained via `echo $PATH`) to your script, so you're running in a sane environnment, identical to your user's.