# String Comparison with Wildcard in Bash Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: bash, if-statement, wildcard

This is probably simple to fix but I can't seem to find a solution that works on here.

I can't figure out why this if statement is evaluating to true:

```
#/bin/bash

err="User dimensions query limit exceeded"

if [ "${err}" != "User"* ]; then
    echo "In the if statement"
    exit 1
fi
```

I've tried various combinations of parentheses and moving the * about, changing != to -ne etc. but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: POSIX `sh` does not support string match like that, you need to use `case` statment if targeting scripts for POSIX compatibility or use bash's extended test operator `[[`

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: The bash-internal command `[` does not support wildcard matching. It behaves in this respect like the external command `[` (see _man test_).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between single and double square brackets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash)

Comment: Also: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because you're using `[ ... ]` instead of `[[ ... ]]`. My *guess* is that filename expansion is being performed on `"User"*`, when you don't want it to be.

Just using the bash-specific `[[` and `]]` should fix it:

```bash
#/bin/bash

err="User dimensions query limit exceeded"

if [[ "${err}" != "User"* ]]; then
    echo "In the if statement"
    exit 1
fi
```

At that point I suspect the condition line could be simplified due to how bash handles `[[ ... ]]` to:

```bash
if [[ $err != User* ]]; then
```

... but I don't know enough about the details to be 100% confident. (It works in my brief tests...)