# Explain Different EXIT Commands in UNIX

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I understand that EXIT command causes the shell or program to terminate.
But what is the difference between the below:

```
exit 2
exit 3
exit 4
exit $?
```

how is exit 2 different from exit 3 and so on

Comment: @tripleee: not really a duplicate, the OP is asking about `exit` not about possibly standard meanings of return code values.

Comment: @isedev: Huh? That's what you use `exit` for.

Answer (score 3):

This is only an exit code. 0 is for fine exit, otherwise it's the error code. `$?` is a shell variable storing the previous exit value (so the program which ran before your one).

Comment: More precisely, it's a shell variable or shell parameter. It's not an environment variable.

Comment: `bash` distinguishes shell variables as a parameter denoted by a name. This excludes the positional parameters (denoted by non-zero numbers) and the special parameters (denoted by various punctuation marks, symbols and 0).

Answer (score 2):

The `exit` command takes a single value which is the value of the process (e.g. shell) return code. `$?` is the return code from the last command executed by the shell.

For instance, the script which exits with a return code corresponding to the first argument:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit $1
```

Would give you:

```
# ./script 1
# echo $?
1
# ./script 2
# echo $?
2
```

Note on most UNIX systems, the return code is limited to a numeric value between 0 and 255, with 0 indicates success and 1-255 providing error information (specific to each process).

Comment: Oh I got it thanks alot for the intel

Answer (score 1):

From the **Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, Chapter 6: Exit and Exit Status**:

> The exit command terminates a script, just as in a C program. It can also return a value, which is available to the script's parent process.

So the `exit` command lets you assign your own exit value, which you could describe in its man page, for example.

The `$?` will return the exit code of the previous command. For example; You write a script that executes `cat example.txt`, which results exit code 1. If you then do `exit $?`, your script will exit with the same code as `cat example.txt`

- More info on exit codes here: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide Chapter 6: Exit and Exit Status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)
- Some info on `$?` here: [What is the $? variable in shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834487/what-is-the-variable-in-shell-scripting)