# What does $? mean in shell?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have script here and I should convert it to python. But one thing that I dont know.

What does this line means:

```
 if [ $? != 0 ]
            then
                    echo "$i NOT FOUND!"
                    retval=255
            fi
```

Need help. Thank you.

Comment: see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#XSTATVARREF

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

That is testing the [exit status (or return code)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the previous command. A value of non-zero traditionally means error.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: [What is the $? variable in shell scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834487/what-is-the-variable-in-shell-scripting)

$? is used to find the error code of the last executed command. Try the following in the shell:

```
ls somebogusfile
echo $?
```

You will get the error code thrown by the ls command.

Comment: If the question is a duplicate of another question that already has an answer, just vote to close it as a dup, don't copy the answer from the other question.

Answer (score 0):

It is the exit value of the last command run in the foreground.

man bash.  :)