# Check linux app status using bash and alert if its not working

Tags: linux, bash

Hi guys the problem is pretty simple I just don't know how to solve this in bash. I want to write simple mule server status checker. I can check it using command:

```
./mule status
```

Then I receive to possible communicates:

If all ok:

```
MULE_HOME is set to /home/mule/mule
Mule is running (3496).
```

And if not ok:

```
MULE_HOME is set to /home/mule/mule
Mule is not running.
```

How can I catch this communicates and for example do simple if / else with - eq

Answer (score 0):

The standard for that is using exitcodes, like all standard executable do. The program needs to use "exit" (without quotes) with some value. The receiver needs to evaluate "$?" (without quotes)

Comment: I just don't get how to write response of running /home/mule/bin/mule status to variable

Comment: You'll understand when reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834487/what-is-the-variable-in-shell-scripting - It's an internal Unix/Linux function, and a great one !