# A shell command to run 'x' number of times while a command keeps failing

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to run a shell command (currently either `sh` or `bash`) which connects to a database. Because the database is still 'warming up', the command fails.

So I was trying to do a loop (let's say ... 100 tries) and each time the command fails, wait 1 second and retry.

If there's an error, this is the start of the string that is dumped to stdout: `Sqlcmd: Error: <snipped>`

Here's what I've been trying:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do
    X='/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -E -S localhost -Q "<some sql statement> "'
    if [[ $X == Sqlcmd: Error:* ]]
        echo "."
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

It's not working as I figure out the string comparison stuff with shell/bash ... but was more making sure if I was on the right track etc.

Comment: Use `$()` to get the output into a bash variable. See my edit .

Comment: I've never done any shell scripting like this before @WernerHenze - so I never knew about status code results for commands, file descriptors, `2>&1` and `$?` idioms, `stdout` and `stderr` are two different things, etc. Lots of shell/bash shell 101 learning, through this. I learnt enough clues from below to get me to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
while true ; do
    if Sqlcmd xxx xxx xxx ; then break ; fi
    # or:
    Sqlcmd xx xxx xxx && break
    sleep 1
done
```

You can also add a counter:

```
for ((n=100;n>0;n--)) ; do
    Sqlcmd xxx xxx xxx
    if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
[[ $n == 0 ]] && echo Timeout && exit 1
```

I'm showing two different ways of testing the return value here, but the first one is preferred (`if cmd ; then ... ; fi`).

`$?` is the return value from the last command, which is `0` when it completed successfully. If it returns `0` even in case of error (which can happen for malformed programs), you can test the output with `grep`:

```
Sqlcmd xxx xxx 2>&1 | grep <error pattern> > /dev/null
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then break ; fi
```

Here we test `$? != 0` because `grep` will return `0` when the *error pattern* has been found.

If you want to get the output result into a variable, run the command with `X=$(Sqlcmd xxx xxx)`. Then you can use bash string comparison:

```
X=$(Sqlcmd xxx xxx)
if [[ "$X" =~ .*error.* ]] ; then
    <handle error here>
fi
```

Note bash can [match regexp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340440/bash-test-what-does-do), which makes it really handy at checking error types.

You can also use a `switch/case` construct:

```
case "$X" in
    *Error:*) echo " Error detected " ;;
    *) break ;;
esac
```

(Note the double `;;`)

Comment: what does `$? == 0` mean plz?

Comment: `$?` stores the exit status of the last executed command; `0` meaning success and `not 0` error (usually, several numbers are used to encode different errors).

Comment: @Pure.Krome it's the return value of the last run command. See my edit.

Comment: AH! thank you :) never knew you could do this (commands have return codes). /me tries ... hmm ... still returns a string???  /me googles for `2>&1` .... Oh! Ok - this is all new to me. So it's redirect `stderror` to `stdout`. kewl. and there's the status code! gotcha! ok .. i think i've got this now...

Comment: @Pure.Krome now you can print the full output of `man bash` and read a page every evening ;)

Comment: To go easier on your cpu, add a `sleep 1` to the end of your `while` loop

Comment: @zwbetz, true. Though sometimes the program itself has an internal timeout too...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up learning all the clues [from @matthieu's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801921/30674). This is what I ended up doing:

```
for i in $(seq 1 30)
do
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P <snip> -S localhost -Q "USE Master" 2>&1

    if [[ $? != 0 ]]
    then
        # Failed
        echo "."
        sleep 1s
    else
        # worked!
        break
    fi
done
```

breakdown for those learning (like me)

- execute a sql query using the `sqlcmd` command. Any errors via `stderr` (that's the `2` in `2>&1`) will be redirected to the console `stdout` (that's the `$1`). REF: [2>&1 shell idiom](https://www.brianstorti.com/understanding-shell-script-idiom-redirect/).
- the result status code is sent to `$?` (REF: [what is bash dollar questionmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834487/what-is-the-dollar-question-mark-variable-in-shell-scripting) ?)
- if it failed(any value that is NOT a zero), then sleep 1 sec and we'll try. Only re-try 30 times, though.
- if we worked (value is zero), then stop trying and go on....

So there we have it! shell/bash shell 101 stuff. good luck!

Comment: Great! Although there's no real point in merging `2>&1` if you're not either removing the whole output (with `> /dev/null`) or piping to another command (`| grep ...`), or getting it into a variable.

Comment: And you could use a `for((i...))`, as well as `echo -n` to show the `.` on the same line instead of on a new line each :)