# How to get the perl exit value from bash script

Tags: bash, perl, perlscript

I'm trying to run perl script through bash, and get the perl's exit value.

perl_script.pl

```
print "test1";
sub a{
  my @array = ("a","b");
  if ($#array ne -1){
   return 1;
  }
  else {return 0;}
}
my $result=a(arg1,arg2);
exit $result;
```

bash.sh

```
VARIABLE_1=$("perl_script.pl" arg1 arg2)
RESULT=$?
```

The '$?' variable keeps returning 0, no matter the exit value is.
Do you know another way to retrieve the perl exit value from bash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A few thoughts on that: add a shebang to your perl script, make it executable, use `./perl_script.pl`

Comment: Your bash code is correct. Something else is going wrong or missing from your question

Comment: @Cyrus It didnt work..

Comment: @jordanm I just edited the question

Comment: Add your bash.sh to your question (no comment).

Comment: `perl -e 'exit 7'` then `echo $?`

Comment: Try `VARIABLE_1=$(perl perl_script.pl arg1 arg2)`

Comment: @Shieryn I copied your perl and bash exactly as it is and did not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Tip: `ne` peforms a string comparions. You should use `!=` to compare numbers.

Comment: Tip: `if ($#array != -1)` is equivalent to `if (@array != 0)` which is equivalent to `if (@array)`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can't get this to behave like you describe, in any variation I can think of.  Something in your real code is different enough --- please check _carefully_.  One thing: add `use warnings; use strict;` to the top of your Perl script so that it alerts you to errors/typos/...   (should _always_ have them).

Answer (score 1):

bash's `$?` will be set to the value passed to `exit`<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
$ perl -e'exit 3'

$ echo $?
3

$ perl -e'exit 4'

$ echo $?
4

$ perl perl_script.pl
test1
$ echo $?
1
```

---

1. If the program dies from an exception, the exit code will be set to a non-zero value. If the program neither dies nor calls `exit`, the exit code will by set to zero.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the root cause of this problem. It is a simple issue but tricky. 
So I would like to share it here.

bash.sh

```
VARIABLE_1=$("perl_script.pl" arg1 arg2)
echo $?
RESULT=$?
```

The echo process has accessed the $?, so the RESULT variables would save the exit value of the echo operation which always turns 0 (successful operation)

The fix

```
VARIABLE_1=$("perl_script.pl" arg1 arg2)
RESULT=$? 
echo $RESULT
```

As the conclusion, the $? has one-time use only right after the script executed.

Comment: Nit: `echo` can exit with a code other than 0. [Example](https://pastebin.com/cdc92cJa)

Comment: Why did you leave the echo out from the question?

Comment: In other words, please don't say the code you posted does something when it's doesn't, and please only post code that exhibits the behaviour you describe.

Comment: So ... do you actually have an extra `echo $?` in your real code (not shown in Q)?   If this is the case I suggest to update the question with a clear added **Note** about it.  Or, are you just posting an observation?  Either way, this isn't an "answer" and I suggest you remove it. As for the [`$?` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters), it's always set by the shell for the last executed command, loosely speaking. See for instance [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834487/what-is-the-dollar-question-mark-variable-in-shell-scripting).