# Why is the fork() return value -1 and why is the wait() exit status not 0?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

In the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    int status;

    pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("I am the child\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        pid = wait(&status);
        printf("I am the parent\n");
        printf("My pid is %i\nMy childs's pid is %i\nMy childs's exit status is     %i\n", getpid(), pid, status);

    }

}
```

This program returns:

```
I am the child
I am the parent
My pid is 16269
My childs's pid is -1
My childs's exit status is 32767
```

1) Why is the child's pid = -1  and not the actual child process number?

2) Why is the child's exit status != 0, as I intended?

Comment: Exit status question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659616/returning-exit-code-from-child

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the child process id, it's because you reassign the `pid` variable, and `wait` returns `-1` on an error.

Regarding the exit status, it's invalid since `wait` failed. But otherwise it's only the eight lowest bits that contain the actual status. First you need to make sure that the `wait` call actually succeeded, then you need to check if the process exited normally with the `WIFEXITED` macro, and then get the actual exit status with the `WEXITSTATUS` macro.

I suggest you read a reference for [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) and the [`<sys/wait.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_wait.h.html) header file.

Comment: But why did the wait fail?  When I run the code, I don't get the error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is a good question, and one only the OP can answer, by checking [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) when the function fails (OP: Hint hint...)

Comment: I added sleep(10) to parent and now I'm getting I am the child
I am the parent
My pid is 16536
My childs's pid is 16539
My childs's exit status is 256. The exit status is still not 0. Is it normal?

Comment: @user3614293 As for the exit status, read my answer again. As for *why* `wait` fails, you have to check `errno`.

Comment: Note that it is the low-order 8 bits of the value passed to `exit()` that are returned by `wait()` et al, but traditionally (if you aren't using the W* macros from `<sys/wait.h>`), those bits are placed in the high order bits of a 16-bit value of the status returned by `wait()`. That is, if the child exits with `exit(0x12)`, then the value returned by `wait()` will be `0x1200`. The low-order 8 bits encode signal number and core dump information. I think that's what you meant, but "it's only the eight lowest bits that contain the actual status" is ambiguous between `wait()` and `exit()`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Diagnosis

I think you must be running the process with the SIGCHLD signal ignored.

When I run your code normally, I get output such as:

```
$ ./wp0
I am the child
I am the parent
My pid is 80161
My childs's pid is 80162
My childs's exit status is     0
$
```

But, if I run it with the SIGCHLD signal ignored, I get:

```
$ (trap '' CHLD; ./wp0)
I am the child
I am the parent
My pid is 80435
My childs's pid is -1
My childs's exit status is     0
$
```

You can check this, perhaps, by running 'trap' at the shell command line. For example, I get:

```
$ (trap '' CHLD; trap)
trap -- '' SIGCHLD
$
```

If using `trap` (with no arguments) doesn't produce an answer analogous to that, then you may need to write a program to interrogate the SIGCHLD status.

Incidentally, one of the first things I did (before going back to your original code), was change the parent's code to:

```
    int corpse = wait(&status);
    printf("I am the parent\n");
    printf("My pid is %i\nMy child's pid was %i\nMy child's exit status is %i\n", getpid(), pid, status);
    printf("My child's corpse was %i\n", corpse);
```

It captures the return value from `wait()` separately from the return value from `fork()`.  Also, I normally print the exit status using `0x%.4X` — in part because I'm anal-retentive about the format for hex values but mainly because the hex value is easier to understand.  You can experiment with the child exiting with different values (perhaps interpreting a command-line argument), and even with it committing suicide with different signals.  While the `WIFEXITED`, `WEXITSTATUS`, `WIFSIGNALED`, `WTERMSIG` etc macros are good, they also are also quite simple and you can see what they do by looking at the hex `status`.

#### Creating a test bed for exit statuses and signals

I extended your program to create a working test harness that allows you to experiment with exit values and signal handling like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c_status = 0;
    int c_signal = 0;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:e:")) != EOF)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 's':
            c_signal = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'e':
            c_status = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-e status][-s signal]", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    sigset_t oset;
    if (pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, 0, &oset) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: pthread_sigmask() failed (%d: %s)\n",
                argv[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (sigismember(&oset, SIGCHLD))
        printf("SIGCHLD is listed in the signal mask\n");
    struct sigaction oact;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, 0, &oact) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: pthread_sigmask() failed (%d: %s)\n",
                argv[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (oact.sa_handler == SIG_DFL)
        printf("SIGCHLD handling is the default\n");
    else if (oact.sa_handler == SIG_IGN)
        printf("SIGCHLD handling is ignoring the signal\n");
    else
        printf("SIGCHLD has a signal handler installed (%p)\n", (void *)oact.sa_handler);
    if (oact.sa_flags & SA_NOCLDSTOP)
        printf("SA_NOCLDSTOP is set\n");
    if (oact.sa_flags & SA_NOCLDWAIT)
        printf("SA_NOCLDWAIT is set\n");

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        printf("I am the child - PID %d\n", (int)getpid());
        if (c_signal == 0)
        {
            printf("I am exiting with status %d\n", c_status);
            exit(c_status);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("I am committing suicide with signal %d\n", c_signal);
            raise(c_signal);
            printf("That didn't work - I'm still here. Oh well!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);
        printf("I am the parent\n");
        printf("My pid is %i\n", getpid());
        printf("My child's pid was %i\n", pid);
        printf("My child's corpse was %i\n", corpse);
        printf("My child's exit status is 0x%.4X\n", status);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            printf("My child exited normally with status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
        {
            printf("My child died from signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
#ifdef WCOREDUMP
            if (WCOREDUMP(status))
                printf("My child produced a core dump\n");
#endif
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I called the program `wp2`.  Running it a few times with different options gave output like this:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
$ ./wp2 -s 4
SIGCHLD handling is the default
I am the child - PID 81188
I am committing suicide with signal 4
I am the parent
My pid is 81187
My child's pid was 81188
My child's corpse was 81188
My child's exit status is 0x0004
My child died from signal 4
$ ./wp2 -s 6
SIGCHLD handling is the default
I am the child - PID 81224
I am committing suicide with signal 6
I am the parent
My pid is 81223
My child's pid was 81224
My child's corpse was 81224
My child's exit status is 0x0086
My child died from signal 6
My child produced a core dump
$ ulimit -c 0
$ ./wp2 -s 6
SIGCHLD handling is the default
I am the child - PID 81489
I am committing suicide with signal 6
I am the parent
My pid is 81488
My child's pid was 81489
My child's corpse was 81489
My child's exit status is 0x0006
My child died from signal 6
$ (trap '' CHLD; ./wp2 -s 6)
SIGCHLD handling is ignoring the signal
SA_NOCLDWAIT is set
I am the child - PID 82300
I am committing suicide with signal 6
I am the parent
My pid is 82299
My child's pid was 82300
My child's corpse was -1
My child's exit status is 0x0000
My child exited normally with status 0
$ ./wp2 -e 6
SIGCHLD handling is the default
I am the child - PID 82434
I am exiting with status 6
I am the parent
My pid is 82433
My child's pid was 82434
My child's corpse was 82434
My child's exit status is 0x0600
My child exited normally with status 6
$
```

The fact that it is easy to interpret the raw status is not an excuse to avoid using the macros provided by POSIX.  Note that `WCOREDUMP` is not specified by POSIX, but is usually available.