# Batch file not opening correct menu option when errorcode is returned

Tags: c, batch-file, if-statement, input

I have written a batch file that gets input from the user to open a file, then displays a menu. Input is then prompted from the user using a .exe C file I wrote and returns the number the user entered, or "-1" if input was not a number. No matter which option I use, the program always open notepad regardless of the menu option. Any help would be great. Ive included code for the batch file and my c input file.

I have checked my C program and it seems to be returning what it is supposed to so it might just be an issue with formatting on the batch side. I included just for reference.

BATCH FILE:

```
REM 1. Clear the screen
REM ------------------------------------------------------
cls


REM 2. Getting user input
REM ------------------------------------------------------

SET /p "FileToProcess=Please enter file(s) to process:" 

REM 3. Checking for file
REM ------------------------------------------------------
IF EXIST "%FileToProcess%" (
    cls
    :MENU
    ECHO 1. Open in Notepad
    ECHO 2. Open in Word
    ECHO 3. Open in Notepad ++
    ECHO 4. Print

    myChoice.exe
    )

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    cd C:\Windows
    notepad.exe %FileToProcess%
    GOTO END
    )

    IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
    WINWORD.EXE %FileToProcess%
    GOTO END
    )

    IF ERRORLEVEL 3 (
    cd C:\Program Files\Notepad++
    notepad++.exe %FileToProcess%
    GOTO END
    )

    IF ERRORLEVEL 4 (
    cd C:\Windows
    notepad.exe /P %FileToProcess%
    GOTO END
    )

    IF ERRORLEVEL -1 (

    ECHO Sorry your input was not accepted!
    pause
    GOTO MENU
    )
REM 4. Display error if no file found
REM -----------------------------------------------------
) ELSE (

    ECHO File does not exist!
    GOTO END

)


:END
```

C INPUT PROGRAM CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)
// main
int main(void)
{
    // variables
    int num;
    char userInput[10] = "";

    // requesting input
    printf("Please enter a menu option: ");
    fgets(userInput, 81, stdin);

    // checks input
    if (sscanf(userInput, "%d", &num) == 1)
    {
        return num;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do not return negative values to your shell. Generally the shell expects a return in the range of `unsigned char`. That is why `stdlib.h` defines `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` as (`0/1`) and not negative values. You will have to check the documentation for `cmd.exe` specifically to find out what it requires.

Comment: `If ErrorLevel 1`, means 'if the error level is `1` or `greater`, you should change them to this format `If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1"`.

Comment: Never, really never return a negative value. On all operating systems a negative exit/return code of an application is not recommended by the kernel writers of the operating system. The reason is quite simple: on a negative integer value the bit width of the exit code matters. For example `-1` is for a 16 bit application `0xFFFF` which is for a 32 bit application positive value `65535`. There is nearly never a reason to use other exit/return values than 0 to 255. And open a cmd window and run `if /?`. The first output help page explains that `if errorlevel 1` means greater or equal 1.

Comment: It is also not recommended to use command `set` with option `/P` to prompt the user for a choice of predefined options. There is the command `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe` for exactly this purpose. See my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) It explains very detailed the differences between `set /P` and `choice` and how to evaluate the user input in a safe and also very efficient way.

Comment: in Windows the return value is a 32-bit signed int, i.e. everything you return in `int main()` will be available to you, unlike on *nix where only the low 8 bits is significant. It can be checked easily with `cmd /c "exit /B -1"; echo %errorlevel%` [Return value range of the main function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5149228/995714#comment51200906_5149267). The [real return type is `UINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) but cmd.exe treats it as signed int

Comment: I also would not advise jumping to a label that is inside a parentheses code block.

Comment: It's not my format, @RocktheFries, it is the correct and recommended syntax. If it's not working for you, then the error is of your making not that of the syntax I provided in my comment.

Comment: It looks like it was an issue combined with my double quotes and my %errorlevel% if statements solved below @Compo. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

REM 1. Clear the screen
REM ------------------------------------------------------
cls

REM 2. Getting user input
REM ------------------------------------------------------

SET /p "FileToProcess=Please enter file to process:" || exit /b 0

REM Strip double quotes
SET "FileToProcess=%FileToProcess:"=%"

REM 3. Checking for file
REM ------------------------------------------------------
IF NOT EXIST "%FileToProcess%" goto :FileNotExist
cls

:MENU
ECHO 1. Open in Notepad
ECHO 2. Open in Word
ECHO 3. Open in Notepad ++
ECHO 4. Print

myChoice.exe

IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (
    cd /d "C:\Windows"
    notepad.exe "%FileToProcess%"
) ELSE IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 2 (
    cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16"
    WINWORD.EXE "%FileToProcess%"
) ELSE IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 3 (
    cd /d "C:\Program Files\Notepad++"
    notepad++.exe "%FileToProcess%"
) ELSE IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 4 (
    cd /d "C:\Windows"
    notepad.exe /P "%FileToProcess%"
) ELSE (
    ECHO Sorry your input was not accepted!
    pause
    GOTO MENU
)
exit /b 0

REM 4. Display error if no file found
REM -----------------------------------------------------
:FileNotExist
>&2 ECHO File does not exist!
exit /b 1
```

- Paths double quoted.
- Change `IF EXIST "%FileToProcess%" (` to
  `IF NOT EXIST "%FileToProcess%" goto :FileNotExist`
  to avoid need from being a large parentheses block.
- Use of `else if` to avoid use of numerous `goto :end`
- `if errorlevel` changed to `if %errorlevel%` for actual
  number instead of number and higher.
- Removed `:end` label as unneeded.

Comment: This did indeed fix my problems I was having! The double quotes led me to an error of "user input was not expected at this time". The error echos now work correctly as well with the change to %errorlevel%.

Comment: From past research into the issue it seems the double quoted paths end up creating the error!

Comment: I am guessing that you enter double quotes or drag'n'drop which adds a path with double quotes which can cause an issue. The code will now strip double quotes immediately after input. The script does not handle multiple file(s) so modified input message.