# Why the process return value is different from what the code returns?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

Consider this code:

```cpp
int main() { return 10'000; }
```

I compile it and run it:

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp -o p
$ ./p
$ echo $?
16
```

Why the output of `$?` is `16`? I also tried with Online Compiler too:

- https://wandbox.org/permlink/ovI5sb9xlh7VpYne

And the process return value is 16. What I'm missing?

---

My environment:

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64 Linux 5.13.10
- Compiler: GCC 11.1.0
- Compiler Additional Flags: `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return value range of the main function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149228/return-value-range-of-the-main-function)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html

Comment: To support the propsed duplicate: The binary representation of `10'000` is `0010011100010000` if you take the 8 lower bits you have `00010000` which is 16.