# Return value of call_usermodehelper() is not correct

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am calling a user-space application, `/usr/bin/myapp`, from a Linux Kernel Module using `call_usermodehelper()`. The `myapp` returns 2228 when it exits. I should receive same value i.e 2228 as a return value of `call_usermodehelper()` in the kernel module. However, I am receiving a different value, that is 46080.

My question is, why I don't receive the value I return from `myapp` as the return value of `call_usermodehelper()`? Note, `myapp` executes successfully when I call it from kernel module using `call_usermodehelper()`. I don't return 0 as a success code. I return 2228 on exit.

Here is the sample code:
**user-space's application code:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s called successfully\n", argv[0]);
    return 2228;
}
```

**Kernel Module's Code:**

```c
int call_userspaceapp()
{
    int ret = -EPERM;
    char *argv[] = {"/usr/bin/myapp", "11", "22", "33", NULL};
    char *envp[] = {"HOME=/", NULL};

    ret = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);

    printk("%s returns value %d", argv[0], ret);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: In Linux you cannot reliably return a value more than 255. E.g. after running your program from the terminal `echo $?` will show 180, which is the lower 8 bits of `2228`. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149228/return-value-range-of-the-main-function) about how much return value can be.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev . Seems like you are telling the truth. However, I am still unable to understand why its like that? 
I mean documentation of call_usermodehelper() never mentions it. There should be some rationale for this thing.

Comment: `call_usermodehelper` doesn't document that because it is not specific to that command. It is property of a program's return value **in general**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I am receiving a different value, that is 46080.

Exit status has 8 bits and return value is just like `waitpid` return value. See userspace definition of `WEXITSTATUS` to access the exit status, which is `46080 >> 8 = 180`, which is equal to the returned exit status `2228 % 256 = 180`. [Here drbd_nl.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/block/drbd/drbd_nl.c#L387) I found an example of `call_usermodehelper` that also accesses the exit status with `(ret >> 8) && 0xff`, just like `WEXITSTATUS`.