# How to catch signals from a shell script which is executing a file which may throw it?

Tags: c, linux, shell, signals

I have a shell script, which is executing a program `fuseIO` which is basically a C program.

Ths idea is, this executable `fuseIO` may throw a `SIGABRT` by an `abort( )` call inside it, in which case, the while loop should exit.

How to accomplish that?

```
i=0
while [ $i != 10 ]
do
   echo "************ Iteration: $i *********\n" 2>&1 |tee -a log.txt
   ./fuseIO 2>&1 | tee -a log.txt // This may throw SIGABRT
   i=`expr $i + 1`
   sleep 1
done
```

Comment: You'll need the `bash` PIPESTATUS environment variable, and you'll need to look for the correct exit status (probably 134, based on 128 plus signal number 6).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: What is this 128?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I just now read about this env variable. `The members of the $PIPESTATUS array hold the exit status of each respective command executed in a pipe` But what, if there was no `pipe` and a `tee` in my script, and it was just executed as `./fuseIO`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I tried this, but no use :-(   `if [ $PIPESTATUS[0] == 134 ]
   then
        echo "Caught a signal"
        exit 1;
   fi`

Comment: It's modestly complex — I'm not sure I can spend the time explaining it right now (and I was hoping someone else would step up and fill in the details for you/me).  In part, see [Exit status codes greater than — possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/)  The WIFSIGALED stuff tells you that a process was signalled, but there's a problem for the shell encoding that, and it does it (or seems to do it), by encoding a signalled exit status as 128 + signal number (129 for HUP, 130 for INT, etc). I'm not sure if `$PIPESTATUS` has to be enabled — check that, too.

Comment: I think you need to use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` to get the number; you probably compared `0[0]` (or `134[0]`) with `134` and they weren't equal.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Just now tested and works great, yeah that's the problem it seems using the `pipe` and the `tee`. Request if you can please add it to your answer for everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part, see [Exit status codes greater than — possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/) The WIFSIGNALED stuff tells you that a process was signalled, but there's a problem for the shell encoding that, and it does it by encoding a signalled exit status as 128 + signal number (129 for HUP, 130 for INT, etc).  To demonstrate shell and signal exit statuses:

```
$ cat killme.sh
#!/bin/bash
kill ${1:-"-INT"} $$
$ ./killme.sh -HUP; echo $?
Hangup: 1
129
$ ./killme.sh -TERM; echo $?
Terminated: 15
143
$ ./killme.sh -QUIT; echo $?
0
$ ./killme.sh -PIPE; echo $?
141
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
...
$
```

This more or less justifies my '128+signum' claim (the `-QUIT` behaviour is unexpected, but explainable after a fashion — it normally dumps core, but didn't because `ulimit` has them disabled).

In `bash`, you can get 'a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command)' via the array [`$PIPESTATUS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables).  For example:

```
$ ./killme.sh | exit 31

$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}
130 31
$
```

This corresponds to the 130 exit status for SIGINT (2) plus the explicit exit status 31.  Note the notation: `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` with the braces around the indexing.  Double quotes and things work like `$*` vs `$@` vs `"$*"` vs `"$@"` for getting all the values in the array.

Applied to your two-part pipeline, you should be able to test:

```
if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} == 134 ]]
then : FuseIO crash with SIGABRT
fi
```

Without the `| tee`, you can simply test `$?`:

```
if [[ $? > 128 && $? < 160 ]]
then : died a signalled death (probably)
else : died an ordinary death
fi
```

The 160 here is also an informed guess; it should be 128+SIGRTMAX.  Note that if a process does `exit 135`, it will be treated as if it was signalled (even if it does not).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was immensely helpful.