# Linux api "system"

Tags: c, linux

A cron job is created, and in the cron job contains the following code:

```
int flag = system("path/main");
printf("system return value: %d \n", flag);
```

the cron job excute every day, and the "flag" is usually "0", However sometimes "falg" is "32512".

I have google the error code, it means "command is not found".

But I need your help to enlighten me, why sometime is ok, sometimes is not.
Does it matter with the relative directory "path/main"

Comment: We would need more details about that "sometimes". Perhaps the job is being executed in a different policy/by a different user.

Comment: Sorry for lack of information. I haven't found any law about "sometimes" yet. Sorry for it.

Comment: [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is returning the status given by [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). Read both man pages I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return code is a bitmask of several things (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179652/3514)). In your case it suggests an exit code of 255 (which is purely from your child process, not due to signal). You should check your `main` program.

Comment: 32512=127*256, so the return code of shell is 127. it means “the command was not
found”

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like to check code more carefully. ^_^

Comment: @iceKing: If the call to `system()` did not return `-1` and `127 == WEXITSTATUS(flag)` then either the shell (`bin/sh`) which should have executed the *program* passed to `system()` had not been found **or** the *program* itself returned `127`. There is clear ambiguity with this value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I reviewed my code carefully, and found that , in a logic, it will change the work directory, so invoking system will return error. Thanks.