# Why does the System V AMD64 ABI say to use syscall?

Tags: c, linux, x86-64

Originally my project had just x86 system call code in it (using 32 bit registers and int $0x80), but then I created a version called src3 that used 64 bit registers and syscall.  That worked, until I created src4 which changed the argument to my _exit function so that it only handles a single byte as the desired process exit status value (in my tests anything that needed more than a byte to represent seemed to overflow in shell printouts, so I'm assuming that process exit status values are only 1 byte in size anyway).  This broke my _exit function until I changed using syscall to int $0x80.

Comment: Uh, what?  I've never been linking against a libc, these are my own definitions.

Comment: Ok, show code of your _exit function.

Comment: The exit syscall takes an int, regardless of how it's getting truncated when returned to e.g. a shell. Though, it would be helpful if you tell us how it broke and what happened, and some code.

Comment: See: [Exit codes bigger than 255 -- possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179565/exitcodes-bigger-than-255-possible/179652#179652).  (No, this question is not a duplicate of that one, but it provides some information that is relevant to this.)

Comment: Does anyone here even know what syscall is?  It's an x86 instruction, meant to replace int $0x80 (I guess, still wondering why syscall is used) for switching to kernel mode and invoking system call invoking code.

Comment: According to a textbook I'm looking at now (The Linux Programming Interface), an equivalent called sysenter (does not mention syscall, making an assumption) is faster than int $0x80 for some reason.

Comment: I still don't get why syscall is used because of how funky it seems to be.