# How to return a number larger than 8 bits from main()?

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7, exitstatus

So as far as I can tell, the exit code returned from `r0` only uses the lowest 8 bits of this register. How wouuld I return a value higher than 8 bits?

Here is the ARMv7 code:

```
@ looping.s
@ calculates sum of integers from 1 to 100
.text
.balign 4
.global main
main:
    MOV r1, #0      @ r1 = 0 as sum
    MOV r2, #0      @ r2 = 0 as counter
loop:
    ADD r2, r2, #1  @ counter = counter + 1
    ADD r1, r1, r2  @ sum = sum + counter
    CMP r2, #100    @ counter - 100
    BLT loop        @ if counter < 100 go to start of loop
    MOV r0, r1      @ Store sum in r0
    BX lr           @ Return summation result to OS
```

Comment: Using a loop to compute 5050?

Comment: is this labsheet 3? xD

Comment: @dangee1705 maybe haha

Comment: @ErikEidt It was an exericse and I just didn't understand how to return more than 8 bits but the answer reply made it clear that you can't return more than 8 bits so you can use the write system call.

Comment: Related: the truncation to 8-bit only happens in the `wait` / `waitpid` API.  A `SIGCHLD` handler can get the full 4 bytes: [ExitCodes bigger than 255, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179565)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exit status of a process is 8 bits in size.  It is not possible to return a larger exit status by normal means.  If you want to output a number larger than 255, you could for example print it to stdout (file descriptor 1) with a `write` system call.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with assembly or ARM in general -- process exit codes on Unix/Linux/POSIX are all 8 bits.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - also 8 bits for MSDOS, Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the `main()` function to perform calculations. In general, **functions** are not restricted to 8-bit return values, so give your actual function a different name and return a larger integer in R0. Invoke your function from inside `main()` and then do whatever you need to do with the return value, perhaps print it to the console.