# Question about wait () and exit () in process manager

Tags: c, linux, process

I am having a problem with wait () and exit () commands in process management in linux.

As far as I learn, the command wait (& val) will change the variable val of the parent program based on the exit state of the child process. That means when i run the command exit (val) the child process will terminate and give exit state 5 but the output of the code is 1281.

### Can anyone explain to me why 1281 instead of 5 ?.Thanks for watching and hope you can answer.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int val = 5;
        if(fork())
            wait(&val);
        else
            exit(val);
        printf("%d\n", val);
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: The status passed to `exit()` is stored in the high-order 8-bits of a 16-bit value returned by `wait()`.  Decimal 1281 corresponds to 0x0501.  The exit status of `5` is present.  What surprises me it the presence of the `1` in the low-order 8 bits.  That normally encodes the signal that terminated the process, or is all zero if the process exited normally.

Comment: You should first check `WIFEXITED(val)` and then `WIFEXITSTATUS(val)` to get the actual return value of your child process.  Read the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitid.2.html) for more info.

Comment: It might help to use `%x` instead of `%d`, so you can see the raw value that comes from `wait`. The correct way to print your value [in decimal] is: `printf("%d\n",(val >> 8) & 0xFF);`. But, better to use the `W*` macros [to check for process being killed instead of just exiting].

Comment: See also [ExitCodes bigger than 255 — possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179565/15168).