# "How does Bash interpret extremely large numbers like '9223372036854775807' as exit status?"

Tags: bash

"I've encountered an interesting scenario when working with Bash. When I provide extremely large numbers like '9223372036854775807' as an exit status for a command, I've noticed that Bash doesn't seem to handle them as expected. Can someone explain how Bash interprets or calculates the exit status in such cases, and what's the limit for exit status values in Bash? Additionally, are there any special considerations for handling large exit status values?"

```
exit 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Open your terminal and type `man bash`. Then type `/EXIT STATUS` to go to the section about exit status.

Comment: See [Exit codes bigger than 255 — possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179565/15168)

Comment: Keep in mind that the status value passed to `exit` has type `int`.  If you pass it a value that doesn't fit into an int, then you have an overflow condition.  The value in the example wouldn't fit into a 32-bit `int`.  What is the size of an `int` on your system?

Answer (score 2):

It's behaving *exactly* as explained in the man page, which you should check.

From `bash` point of view, you are doing the same as

```
exit $(( 9223372036854775807 % 256 ))
```

as you can check via `$?`.