# x86 Assembly: handling exponent 1 in power calculation

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att, exponentiation

I have this code I wrote in x86. The code does a power of the first number I'm pushing to the queue by the second one.

Now all cases work as expected except one case that's when the second number equals `$1` and then for some reason the output is 0, however I didn't managed to determine why when I debugged it...

(BTW I'm using `mul` instruction that one time put the output in `%rax` and one time in `%rdx`, so I did a logic that determines from which one to take the output each time (by counting the iterations). It seems to me that this implementation is quite bad so I would like to hear how you would deal with that).

Here's the code:

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
  pushq $3
  pushq $1
  call power_load_values
  jmp exit_with_solution
 
power_load_values:
  mov %rsp,%rbp
  mov 4(%rsp),%rcx
  mov 4(%rsp),%rax
  mov 8(%rsp),%rbx
  jmp power_loop
 
return_to_main:
  mov %rbp,%rsp
  add $8,%rbp
  ret
 
power_loop:
  inc %rdx
  cmp $1,%rbx
  je return_to_main ;if the second number is 1 so the output is just the first one (no need to do power)
 
  cmp $0,%rbx
  je set_as_one ;power zero is one
 
  mul %rcx
  dec %rbx
 
  test $1,%rdx ;checking if its odd or even. event - take from rax, odd - take from rdx 
  jnz from_rdx
  jz from_rax
 
from_rdx:
  mov %rdx,%rcx
  mov 8(%rsp),%rax ;because rax is being used for 'mul' operator and it resets after calling it
  jmp power_loop
 
from_rax:
  mov %rax,%rcx
  mov 8(%rsp),%rax ;because rax is being used for 'mul' operator and it resets after calling it
  jmp power_loop
 
set_as_one:
  mov $1,%rcx
  jmp return_to_main
 
exit_with_solution:
  movl $1,%eax
  mov %rcx,%rbx
  int $0x80
```

I would like to hear some advice from you guys.

Comment: After MUL writes the 128-bit product to RDX:RAX, the low bit of RDX (bit #64 of the full product) being odd or even doesn't tell you anything useful.  And using that RDX value as the multiplier for the next iteration makes no sense.  If you're producing a 64-bit result, just use `imul %rcx, %rax` to repeatedly multiply by a copy of the original value.  (Or handle the exponent with shift and bit-test, like how you can multiply with shift and add instead of just repeated add, you can exponentiate in O(log m) instead of O(m) time.  Then you would use `test`.)

Comment: When you single-step in GDB, look at the RDX value.  And read the manual for mul`: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul

Comment: @PeterCordes, Hey, Thanks for your answer!
I did looked on rdx and it says its 1... its also not true but still the answer is 0

Comment: After `mul`, it's zero unless your numbers are huge.  After `inc %rdx` which you do for no apparent reason, it's `1`.  On the first iteration, you haven't even set RDX when that inc/cmp/jcc runs.  Also, one of the values you load is half the return address and half of the last push.  This is 64-bit code so `call` pushes an 8-byte return address, so the first stack arg is at `8(%rsp)` on function entry.  The normal x86-64 calling convention is to pass args in registers.

Comment: @PeterCordes. As I saw when I debugged it: at the end there's value of 0x10000000 on %rcx, and it's being pushed to %rbx. However - the exit status code is 0 and not 1... (Although it's not the expected output of the code - but still strange). and I didn't knew that the calling convention is to pass in register, on the book I'm reading it says to push it to queue - can you reference something that I could learn from some conventions such as this?

Comment: The 32-bit `int $0x80` and 64-bit `syscall` ABIs don't take any args on the stack, so `push` isn't useful.  No idea what queue you're talking about either.  A process exit status is truncated to 8 bits, so from outside the process you can only see the low 8 bits of EBX.  With `strace` you might be able to see the full 32-bit arg passed to the `_exit()` system call.  See [Exit codes bigger than 255 — possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/179565) about other POSIX APIs which a parent process could possibly use to retrieve a full 32-bit status.  (Still not 64-bit, `_exit` takes only 32 bits).

Comment: @PeterCordes, I meant stack, not queue, my mistake